# Is null a Java keyword?

Tags: java, null, keyword

Is `null` is a keyword in Java?

Comment: Why is this question -1?

Comment: probably because it would've taken less time to google the answer than to ask it. The second google result has the answer in the summary, you wouldn't even have to click the link.

Comment: No it is literal in Java.You can what null is [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java/7258515#7258515

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.It is not a keyword.

Answer (score 47):

Not according to the [Java Language Specification list of keywords](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9). On the other hand, 
 this doesn't compile:

```
int null = 10;
```

The [rules for identifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) specify that:

> An identifier is an unlimited-length
>   sequence of Java letters and Java
>   digits, the first of which must be a
>   Java letter. An identifier cannot have
>   the same spelling (Unicode character
>   sequence) as a keyword (§3.9), boolean
>   literal (§3.10.3), or the null literal
>   (§3.10.7).

I'm not sure what the benefit of making it not-a-keyword is, to be honest.

Comment: Lol, this answer implies that there are implementations of Java that accept null as a keyword.

Comment: Gamecat, the way i read it, it says clearly the spec does _not_ consider null a keyword.

Answer (score 11):

Not a [*keyword*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9) - the [*null literal*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.7).

<s>an [*identifier*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8)</s> (oops, no it isn't)

Comment: It's not an identifier either, according to http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#40625

Answer (score 9):

`null` is a literal similar to `true` and `false` in Java. These are not keywords because these are the values of something. As `null` is the value of a reference variable, `true` is the value of a boolean variable.

Answer (score 7):

*null* is a literal, in the same sense that *false*, *10*, and  *'\n'* are literals. It's not a "keyword", technically, but it is a character string that is treated specially by the compiler if the compiler encounters it in a java source file.

So, no, you cannot name a variable "null". The lexical analyzer will decide that it is not an identifier.

Answer (score 3):

No.
See this for complete list: [Java Language Keywords](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html)

Answer (score 1):

*true* and *false* are also literals.
Java trivia: *const* and *goto* are keywords.

Answer (score 0):

No. null is not a keyword in Java.

Answer (score 0):

It represents a special value but it's not a keyword in Java,
and it doesn't mean that we can use it as  an identifier. It's restricted to be used as an identifier and that is obvious because we cannot have a special value as an identifier  because the compiler will treat that word (null) as special value, not as identifier.