# Are true and false keywords?

Tags: java

Are `true` and `false` keywords in Java?

Comment: This question was in fact answered in your previous question on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519631/java-keywords

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No. `true` and `false` are literals.

Answer (score 27):

Here's the complete list of [Java Language Keywords](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html). In particular, note that

> `true`, `false`, and `null` might seem like
>   keywords, but **they are actually
>   literals**; you cannot use them as
>   identifiers in your programs.

Comment: Can you explain the difference?

Comment: It's syntactical. Literals represent values, like "Hello" and 42, whereas keywords don't.

Comment: OK but why isn't true,false,null a keyword as well as a literal?

Comment: "Keywords" and "literals" are mutually exclusive, by their definition.

Comment: i the java language specification, it says "The tokens are the identifiers (§3.8), keywords (§3.9), literals (§3.10), separators (§3.11), and operators (§3.12) of the syntactic grammar.". so by saying "false, ..." is not a keyword, that maybe simplifies matters. i dunno

Comment: Thanks Zach. Now bookmark the link, it will refrain you from posting lot of other questions.

Comment: @CAD1337: what would be gained if they where keywords?

Answer (score 1):

No, but they're reserved.

Answer (score 1):

**No** true, false are not keywords they are actually literals; 
you cannot use them as identifiers in your programs.
Here is the complete list of [keywords in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html)

```
abstract        continue            for           new           switch
assert***       default         goto*             package   synchronized
boolean     do                  if            private   this
break       double          implements    protected throw
byte        else            import            public    throws
case        enum****            instanceof    return    transient
catch       extends         int           short         try
char        final           interface     static    void
class       finally         long              strictfp**    volatile
const*      float           native            super         while

*   not used
**  added in 1.2
*** added in 1.4
****    added in 5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

No. true and false are literals in java. Literals are something which are actual values not the variable names. Though they are not part of keywords list of java they are considered to be the reserved ones. If you try to use them as variables you will get compile error saying - invalid VariableDeclaratorId

Comment: sir you are awesome :)