# What does it mean when Spring MVC @Controller returns null view name?

Tags: spring-mvc

I downloaded the code for the [Spring MVC 3 Showcase](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/07/22/spring-mvc-3-showcase/). One thing puzzles me (well, more than one), why does this (edited for concision) sample return `null`?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/form")
public class FormController {
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processSubmit(@Valid FormBean form, 
                BindingResult result, 
                WebRequest webRequest, 
                HttpSession session, Model model) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
             return null;
        } else {
            session.setAttribute("form", form);
            return "redirect:/form";            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If a controller returns a null view name, or declares a `void` return type, Spring will attempt to infer the view name from the request URL.

In your case, it will assume the view name is `form`, and proceed on that assumption.

It does this using an implementation of `RequestToViewNameTranslator`, the default implementation of which is `DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator`, the [javadoc for which](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator.html) explains the exact rules it applies.

Comment: Does a RequestToViewNameTranslator bean have to be explicitly provided, or does Spring provide this out of the box?

Answer (score 4):

`AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod()` takes care of invoking handler methods. Here, a `ModelAndView` will be retrieved via `ServletHandlerMethodInvoker.getModelAndView()`.

In your case, `getModelAndView()` gets provided the handler method's `null` return value. The `getModelAndView()` method checks for the return value's type, but [as in Java null is never an instanceof any class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java), that method's logic will create a new `ModelAndView`. A new `ModelAndView` has initially its view property set to `null`.

Then later back up the call stack, in `DispatcherServlet.doDispatch()`, there is a test if the `ModelAndView` object has a `View` associated with it ( `mv.hasView()` ). Because `view == null`, `doDispatch()`'s logic calls `mv.setViewName(getDefaultViewName(request))`. It delegates to the registered `RequestToViewNameTranslator`, whose default implementation is  `DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator`. This subclass translates the request URI into a view name, in your case `form`.

Later in `doDispatch()`, via `render()` -> `resolveViewName()`, this sample's `ViewResolver`s are provided with the view name `form`. Only one `ViewResolver`, `InternalResourceViewResolver` is used in this sample. Also, this `InternalResourceViewResolver` was configured in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml` to add the prefix `/WEB-INF/views/` and the suffix `.jsp` to the view name. So in total, it will create a `View` using the JSP file `/WEB-INF/views/form.jsp`. Luckily, a JSP file exists at exactly this location.