# Spring MVC: @ResponseBody Get method return void

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I have a controller method which should return some data. I'm wondering why despite it's `GET` and marked with `@ResponseBody` it's `void`.

```
@ResponseBody    
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/data", method = GET)
public void getData(....) { // < Question: how it can be void?
  ....
  dataService.streamData(query); // < this method is also void
}
```

**Question:** *What spring returns in this case? Is this method useless?*

Comment: I too looking for this response.

Comment: I just tested it returns null, I feel this should be avoid.

Answer (score 2):

If a controller `returns a null view name`, or `declares a void return type`, Spring will attempt to infer the view name from the request URL.

It does this using an implementation of `RequestToViewNameTranslator`, the default implementation of which is `DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator`

complete info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875255/what-does-it-mean-when-spring-mvc-controller-returns-null-view-name)

Comment: thanks. But in my case it's an API method, response of which should be parsed to `Backbone.Collection`. Actual result on client-side is `[]`

Comment: @V_B then we might need to dig in deeper.

Comment: moreover in your example their method returns `String`. Isn't it a case?

Comment: Yeah, let's do that. What I need to check in order to dig in deeper?

Comment: @V_B first of all request you add more info to your question, is it like a normal Spring MVC or Spring as rest service, maybe some service side code, or which method is calling it etc.

Comment: this method is called with usual Javascript AJAX request

Comment: Yeah it's an usual Spring MVC.