# The method is ambigous - Java

Tags: java, overloading, overriding

I was trying to some examples and was not able to understand the reason for following code error in the following example

```
public class Test {
public static void print(Integer object){
    System.out.println("object");
}
public static void print(String string){
    System.out.println("String");
}
public static void main(String... args){
    print(null);
}
}
```

I am getting error as: ***The method print(Integer) is ambiguous for the type Test***

but when I am trying the same example by changing Integer to Object the code compiles fine and gives output as **String**

```
public class Test {
public static void print(Object object){
    System.out.println("object");
}
public static void print(String string){
    System.out.println("String");
}
public static void main(String... args){
    print(null);
}
}
```

Can anyone please help me in understanding why the method with Object in its signature is required when the output is from the method which is having String in it. And what is the reason for the ambiguous type error.

Comment: String and Integer are not related, String and Object are. This is somewhere in the JLS..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Integer` and `String` are not in same hierarchies. It means you can't assign `String` into `Integer` and vice-verse.

but it's not case with `String`and `Object` because in java every class extends `Object` class by default.

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) (JLS) in section 15.12 [Method Invocation Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12) explains in detail the process that the compiler follows to choose the right method to invoke.

There, you will notice that this is a *compile-time* task. The JLS says in subsection 15.12.2:

> This step uses the name of the method and the types of the argument expressions 
>   to locate methods that are both accessible and applicable
>   There may be more than one such method, in which case the [**most specific**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) one is chosen.

Read more about [Java overloading rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901259/java-overloading-rules)

See [Method overloading and choosing the most specific type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361639/method-overloading-and-choosing-the-most-specific-type)

---

Look at below sample code where `Integer` and `Number` are in same hierarchy that why it's valid.

```
class Test {
    public  void print(Integer object) {
        System.out.println("object");
    }

    public  void print(Number string) {
        System.out.println("String");
    }
}
new Test().print(null);
```

[image]

Comment: Or in short in case of Integer and String as either one of the type is eligible to be 'null' hence the ambiguity is caused but in case of Object and String the ambiguity is there but as String can be labelled a "More Specific" type of "Object" hence as per the Java Spec you mentioned it's the one which gets picked up for execution. Please correct me if I am wrong!

Answer (score 3):

Null doesn't have a type in Java. When you call `print(null)`, the compiler doesn't know whether you want to call the `print(String)` function or the `print (Integer)` function.

The solution is to explicitly cast into the type you want called

```
print((Integer)null);
```

or

```
print((String)null);
```

Comment: The only answer that explained the problem in one sentence and then showed how to fix it. Very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

A common practice to disambiguate methods such as this is adding type information into the method name.  This has the advantage of making the code explicit and clear, rather than using function overloading to resolve which method is called.

```
public class Test {
public static void printInteger(Integer object){
    System.out.println("object");
}
public static void printString(String string){
    System.out.println("String");
}
public static void main(String... args){
    printInteger(null);
}
}
```