# Null value in method parameter

Tags: java, null, type-conversion, overloading

I have the following code

```
import java.util.List;

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      test(null);
    }

    static void test(List<Object> a){
        System.out.println("List of Object");
    }
    static void test(Object a){
        System.out.println("Object");
    }
}
```

and I got following output in console

```
List of Object
```

Why doesn't this call `test(Object a)`? Can you some one explain how it took "List as" `null`?

Comment: Related: [Overloaded method selection based on the parameter's real type](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1572322/1065197), [Method overloading and choosing the most specific type](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9361639/1065197).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a nutshell, the *most specific* method among the overloads is chosen.

In this case the most specific method is the one that takes `List<Object>` since it's a subtype of `Object`.

The exact algorithm Java uses to pick overloaded methods is quite complex. See [Java Language Specification section 15.12.2.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) for details.

Answer (score 4):

Always specific first, in cases like that. If you change List to String, it will print the same thing. Every class is child of Object, so if it have to overload, will be to the more specific class.