# Comparison of two null objects from two different types

Tags: java, types, null, comparison

```
public void m1(Integer f) {
    ...
}

public void m1(Float f) {
    ...
}

public void main() {
    m1(null); // error: the method m1(Integer) is ambiguous for the type Main
    m1((Integer) null); // success
}
```

Given the above example, we can admit *in some ways* that `null` is typed. So why do the following lines print `true`? Sure `o1` and `o2` both have no value (i.e. `null`), but they aren't from the same type (`Integer` vs `Float`). I firstly thought `false` would have been printed.

```
Integer i = null;
Object o1 = (Object) i;
Float f = null;
Object o2 = (Object) f;
System.out.println(o1 == o2); // prints true

// in short:
System.out.println(((Object) ((Integer) null)) == ((Object) ((Float) null))); // prints true
```

Comment: Null does not have a type:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java

Comment: `null` is typed; see my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All `null` values are untyped and are equal. You can pass it to different reference types but it makes no difference for comparison purposes.

It is not the `null` value which is typed but the reference to the null which can be typed.

A common question is what happens here

```
class A {
    public static void hello() { System.out.println("Hello World"); }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        A a = null;
        a.hello();
        System.out.println("a is an A is " + (a instanceof A)); // prints false.
    }
}
```

The *compiler* sees the type of `a` as an `A` so the static method is called.  But the value referenced is `null` and untyped.

The only operations you can perform with `null` without causing a NullPointerException is to assign or pass it without examining it or comparing it with another reference.

BTW

In short: The compiler will select a method based on the type of the reference, at runtime the execution is based on the class of the object referenced. At runtime `null` is treated as any type or no type or you get a NullPointerException if you try to dereference it.

Answer (score 1):

"==" in Java checks to see if it is the same instance rather than simply "are they equal?".  There is no concept of multiple instances of null in Java.  If you compare null to null, you will always receive true regardless of type.

The reason why you cannot then pass null as an argument to a method with the same name as another with different parameter types is because either method could be a candidate to be called without further type context.  Rather than guess which one that might be, it correctly indicates an error.

Answer (score 1):

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1

`null` belongs to the "null type". The "null type" has only one value - the `null`.

The null type is a subtype of every reference type. Therefore we can do

```
Integer i = null;   
(Integer)null
```

In another word, `null` is a valid value in every reference type.

(Think of a type as a set of values; the types of a value is the sets it belongs to;  "subtype" means "subset". )

Answer (score 0):

Given the above example, we can admit that null is NOT typed: when you call `m1(null)`, compiler cannot determine the type of the actual parameter and cannot decide which method to invoke. All nulls are equal and not typed, and so `(null==null)==true`.

Answer (score 0):

Null does not have a type, but a *reference* (to `null` or anything else) has a type. We can declare two reference variables with different types, but the `null` they refer to is the same thing in both cases:

```
Integer a = null;
Double  b = null;
```

In your example,

```
m1((Integer) null);
```

the compiler uses the type of the *reference* it is passed to work out which overloaded method to call, not the type of the `null` value itself.

Answer (score 0):

In your example it proves that the compiler cannot identity the type (of null) and decide which method to call. So you have to explicity give the type. Also `null == null` will be always true; no matter whatever cast you do it doesnt change or give null a type.
This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java) has a long description on `null`.