# Why does this code go into the wrong block of my method?

Tags: java, string, null

I have a query I am making a call to a method like this from another piece of code within same class

```
String message = "null";
//In this case have too show the Yes/No button screen
return performManualVerification(transaction, patientId, scriptInfo, message);
```

As seen above the message contain string null I am passing this to the below method  but while debugging I was checking that it was not going for null check block it should go inside null check block it is going on No phone block. Please advise

```
private int performManualVerification(ITransaction transaction,
      String patientId, String scriptInfo, String message)
  {

    if (message.equalsIgnoreCase(null))
    {
      int UserResponse = messageBox.showMessage("patientinfoVerification",
          null, IMessageBox.YESNO);

      if (UserResponse == IMessageBox.YES) {
               Map<String, List<String>> ppvValidatedinfo = getValidatedPatientData(transaction, patientId, scriptInfo);
        if(ppvValidatedinfo.get(patientId) != null){

          return MANUALLY_VERIFIED; // manually verified
        }      

      } 
        return RETURN_SALE;   
    }


    messageBox.showMessage("Nophone", null, IMessageBox.OK);

    int UserResponse = messageBox.showMessage("patientinfoVerification",
        null, IMessageBox.YESNO);

    if (UserResponse == IMessageBox.YES) {

      Map<String, List<String>> ppvValidatedinfo = getValidatedPatientData(transaction, patientId, scriptInfo);
      if(ppvValidatedinfo.get(patientId) != null){

        return MANUALLY_VERIFIED; // manually verified
      }      

    } 
      return RETURN_SALE;   
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

> String message = "null";

This is a string with value as null. But what you need is,

```
String message = null;
```

Read about [What is null in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java) post and the answer written by @polygenelubricants was well explained.

And also look at this constraint, this will give you a `NullPointerException` if message is null.

```
 if (message.equalsIgnoreCase(null))
```

So first check whether it is null or not.

```
if(message == null) {
   // do something.
} else {
   // Do something.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get around this issue, you should be using "null" with quotes and not just `null`, which has a different meaning.

- "null" is just another Java `String.
- `null` (without quotes) is a literal which can be assigned to object references usually meaning they don't refer to any object.

On the other hand, if you just want to assign the reference a null value, you should use the null literal and not the `String` and you can compare it like this:

```
    String s = null;
    if(s == null)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use null in quotes for getting the expected result.