# Null Exception array

Tags: java

Hi I am working in string array and It seeming wont add the data in the array keep me getting an error or null exception

```
public boolean addCategory(String description){
if(numCategories <= maxArrayCategories){
    arrayCategories[numCategories] = description;
    numCategories++;
    return true;}
else {return false;}}
```

Is the problem the function?

Comment: how have you defined `arrayCategories` ?

Comment: private String[] arrayCategories;

Comment: What line is it breaking on?  where is `arrayCatagories` defined and initialized?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`arrayCategories` is `null`, you need to create the array itself in order to use it:

```
arrayCategories = new String[maxArrayCategories];
```

Somewhere at the top of your code, if this is a class member, probably in the constructor.

In Java [*null* is a language literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java) meaning that the reference (in this case your array) point to nowhere. A [NullReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception) means you are trying to access a value that has not been initialized yet, or was set explicitly to null (In this case, you are trying to set an array cell, where the array has not been initialized yet).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you have never initialized `arrayCategories` array.That's why it is throwing `NullPointerException`. You must initialize an array before using it. For example if you already knowing that the `arrayCategories` is going to have `maxArrayCategories` number of elements then you should initialize the array before calling the method `addCategory` using:

```
arrayCategories = new String[maxArrayCategories];
```

And also make sure that the condition to be checked should be

```
if(numCategories < maxArrayCategories)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Hi I hope numCategories is like a index and has value 0 and maxArrayCategories is the length of array and hope you have initialized the array arrayCategories then please try this.
//it would be work.

public boolean addCategory(String description){
if(numCategories < maxArrayCategories-1){
    arrayCategories[numCategories] = description;
    numCategories++;
    return true;}
else {return false;}}
```