# java.lang.NullPointerException in Filtering a ListView

Tags: android, listview, filter, adapter

I'm trying to do a search bar that filter a listview But I'm facing this error in this line `filteredProjects.add(container.getProjects().get(i));` and I can't figure out why? Any idea what the problem might be? Thank you for helping I would apreciate it.

```
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").create();

    final ProjectContainer container = gson.fromJson(resultat,
            ProjectContainer.class);
    final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */
    adaptateur = new ProjectAdapter(ProjectActivity.this,
            R.layout.ligne_project, container);

    lv.setAdapter(adaptateur);

    // setListAdapter(adaptateur);
    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
    /**
     * Enabling Search Filter
     * */
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @SuppressWarnings("null")
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            ProjectContainer filteredProjects = null;

            if (!s.toString().equals("")) {
                for (int i = 0; i < container.getProjects().size(); i++) {
                    if (container.getProjects().get(i)
                            .getAbbreviation().toString().contains(s)) {
                        filteredProjects.setProjects(null);
                        filteredProjects.add(container.getProjects()
                                .get(i));
                    }
                }
                adaptateur = new ProjectAdapter(ProjectActivity.this,
                        R.layout.ligne_project, filteredProjects);

                lv.setAdapter(adaptateur);
            } else {
                adaptateur = new ProjectAdapter(ProjectActivity.this,
                        R.layout.ligne_project, container);
                lv.setAdapter(adaptateur);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

And this is my ProjectContainer.class :

```
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

    public class ProjectContainer {
        @SerializedName("project")
        List<Project> projects;

        public List<Project> getProjects() {
            return projects;
        }

        public void setProjects(List<Project> projects) {
            this.projects = projects;
        }

        public void add(Project project) {
            projects.add(project);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate `filteredProjects`. Try changing

```
ProjectContainer filteredProjects = null;
```

to

```
ProjectContainer filteredProjects = new ProjectContainer();
```

You are also setting the `projects` list in `filteredProjects` to null at this line:

```
filteredProjects.setProjects(null);
```

This will cause a `NullPointerException` when you call `filteredProjects.add(..)`. You need to assign a new listm instead of null.

```
filteredProjects.setProjects(new List<Project>());
```

I can recommend [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2707333/1401257) answer about null values if you aren't entirely sure what it is.

Answer (score 1):

```
  public void add(Project project) {
        projects.add(project);
    }
```

In the above line you used an uninitialized instance `projects`.

So better call `setProjects` method before calling `add` method

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I updated my question and I called setProjects method before calling add method but I got java.lang.NullPointerException in this line                         filteredProjects.setProjects(null);

Answer (score 1):

You aren't calling setProjects in the code snippet above, just defining it. Therefore, uninitialised objects are null, per the [language definition](http://think.bradsbrain.com/2010/04/java-default-values-for-objects-and.html), and will throw a [NullPointerException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) when access is attempted.