# What is the meaning of null?

Tags: java, string, null

```
String s="";
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
    s=s.concat(strLine);
```

When I used this code I get the string I expect from the file ..
But if I used

```
String s = null;
```

What I get is `null` as the result of the s string. Can anyone explain me the reason for this?

Comment: I think you should be getting `NPE` when using `String s = null;`

Comment: @Sankalp: Yup, me too - I suspect the real code uses the string concatenation operator.

Comment: BTW concatenating lines this way will put all the text on one line without a separator.

Comment: Have a look to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java

Answer (score 9):

Firstly, I suspect that's *not* your code - or it would throw a `NullPointerException`. I suspect you've *actually* got:

```
s = s + strLine;
```

After that, it's very simple - concatenating *any* string with a `null` String reference will give you `null`:

```
String x = null;
String y = x + "a";
System.out.println(y); // nulla
```

From [section 15.18.1 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1) (string concatenation):

> If only one operand expression is of type String, then string conversion (§5.1.11) is performed on the other operand to produce a string at run time.

Then from [section 5.1.11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11):

> If the reference is null, it is converted to the string "null" (four ASCII characters n, u, l, l).

Note that your code is extremely inefficient at the moment - you should be using a `StringBuilder`.