# Why I can pass null as argument to method without null being instance of accepted parameters?

Tags: java

```
public static String instanceTest(Comparable cmp) {
    if (cmp == null) {
        return "null";
    }
    else return cmp.toString();
} 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Comparable comp = null;
    //comp = new FileReader(""); cannot be converted
    System.out.println(null instanceof Comparable);
    System.out.println(comp instanceof Comparable);
    System.out.println(instanceTest(null));
}
```

This example confuses me. The `instanceTest` method accepts only Comparable.`null` is not an object and cannot be instance of Comparable.But passing null to `instanceTest` is compiled and even can be executed.Why? Even more confusing - I can create a Comparable object `comp` that points to `null`. The `instanceof` fails with the `comp instanceof Comparable` but I cannot convert the object to another type that is not Comparable.Obviously instanceof  checks the object but not the reference? But the reference also contains some information about it's type ? So is there a way to check the type of the reference??

Comment: This answer sums null up nicely:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1) states

> The null reference can always undergo a widening reference conversion
>   to any reference type.

where [widening reference conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.5) is defined as

> A widening reference conversion exists from any reference type S to
>   any reference type T, provided S is a subtype (§4.10) of T.

So although `null` isn't an instance of type `Comparable` (it's not an instance at all, it's a reference), it can be used in the place of a reference of type `Comparable` (or any other reference type).

> So is there a way to check the type of the reference??

You are already doing it with `==` and `instanceof`.