# How to Compare null?

Tags: java, null

How do we compare null values ?
For example, I am trying to compare null by

```
class_name == "null"
```

But the code doesn't checks if the class is null.
What's wrong ?

Comment: Use `class_name == null` or improve your question if I didn't get the meaning.

Comment: +1 .. i messed a lot once past back on the same issue :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are comparing it to the *reference* of the *String* "null".

Remove the double quotes so you get the [special `null` type (JLS)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html).

You want:

```
class_name == null
              ↑
```

Comment: can we use === instead of == ??

Comment: No. Java != JavaScript.

Comment: Please, don't give even a *hint* of the notion that one can *compare strings* with `==` :)

Answer (score 1):

`class_name == null` because in your way you compare it to [string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html) not to null

Comment: is null an object or a data type, in Java ?

Comment: I'm sorry null is not an object in java (It is object in JavaScript) null is special type in java if you want more information about it in java you can look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java

Answer (score 0):

```
if(class_name == null)
    // do something;
```