# Using Null in an example

Tags: java, null

I'm doing homework and I have to rewrite the StringTokenizer class in Java. When the `nextToken()` method is called and there are no more tokens my method should return a value of null.  My homework is complete except this part. I don't understand what exactly that means and what I'm supposed to do.

I've searched this website for answers but really don't understand the answers or examples given. My question is how does null fit into the methods `nextToken()` or `hasMoreTokens()` in the `StringTokenizer` class in Java? 


Some of the other posts on this subject that I've looked at. [What is null in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `nextToken()` returns a `String`, all you need to do when there are no more tokens is:

```
return null;
```

You can use the keyword `null` as the value for any Java `Object`. It simply means "no object".

This won't work for `hasMoreTokens`, which is supposed to return a `boolean` value (either `true` or `false`). Primitive values (`boolean`, `int`, etc.) are not objects, you cannot use `null` as a return value in those situations.

Comment: That seems simple. Thanks.