# What really happens when an uninitialized instance variable is initialized?

Tags: java

When I declare an instance variable, such as:

```
BSTNode node;
```

I know that `node` is now null, since the instance variable is not initialized. But is some memory allocated to store the value of `null`, and is `node` now a reference to that location?

I tried using

```
System.out.println(node);
```

Hoping that I would see the address of the reference, but just saw `"null"` printed out. Why do I not see an address?

Comment: There's no such thing in Java as the "address" of a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instance variables are initialized to their default values, if the code doesn't explicitly initialize them.  All reference variables are initialized to `null`, per [JLS Section 4.12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a default value when it is created (§15.9, §15.10):

...

> For all reference types (§4.3), the default value is null.

When a `null` is passed to `System.out.println`, the string literal `"null"` is outputted. The Javadocs for `println` defer to [the `print` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#print%28java.lang.String%29) to cover what happens when a `null` is passed:

> If the argument is null then the string "null" is printed.

There is no address because there is no object yet.

Comment: Bohemian states that memory is still allocated, so would the memory location be referred by the variable initialized with a default value of null?

Comment: Yes, memory is still allocated for the reference variable itself, but not for any object.  The value `null` is a Java construct that is treated specially.  Think of it as a special value that refers to no object / no memory location at all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, memory is allocated and a value assigned no matter the initialization.

There is no such thing as "uninitialized": there's explicitly initialized, or initialized with the default value.

Comment: Is there a way I could find the location of a variable that has been initialized with the default value of null?

Comment: What do you mean, the "location"?  It's a field stored in the object of the enclosing class.

Comment: Java doesn't use "memory addresses" for variables like C does. The value could be anywhere in memory and may move around as the JVM see fit. The variable is an abstraction of the real memory location, which is not accessible to code.

Comment: If java doesn't use "memory addresses", what is it that I see when I use System.out.print(someObject)? I always thought that was a memory location?

Comment: It's the identity hash code. See [`System.identityHashCode(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode(java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 0):

Java has no pointers like C/C++. You will never See the memory pointer where you object is located. And if you would get it, it might even chance as garbage collection might move it.

If you print an object, it is made a string calling toString().

Answer (score 0):

"Is `node` now a reference to that location?"

How is `null` represented in the memory?

That is implementation specific, and you won't be able to see the representation of null in a pure Java program. (But null is represented as a zero machine address / pointer in most if not all Java implementations.)

[There is already a very detailed answer to this question in Stackoverflow: You should check it out!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java)

Also watch this [video by Tony Hoare, "Null References: The Billion Dollar Mistake"](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare).