# Java if statement: How to find if value is not equal null?

Tags: java, if-statement

I am trying to allow user to key in two inputs and check user have key in both value or not but it come out error. here is example code

```
public static void add train{
int a,b;

System.out.println("Enter train ID");
  System.out.println("(**Example '1001'**)");
  b=sc.nextInt();
  System.out.println("1. to Night Safari");
  System.out.println("2. to River Safari");
  System.out.println("3. to Zoo Main Entrance ");
  System.out.println("Enter a destination for the train");
  a= sc.nextInt();
  }
```

this is my previous code for getting input from user, and now I need to book train ticket

```
public static void book(){
System.out.println("Where do you want to go?");
  System.out.println("1. to Night Safari");
  System.out.println("2. to River Safari");
  System.out.println("3. to Zoo Main Entrance ");
  a=sc.nextInt();
if (a==1 && b !=null){//incomparable types: int and <nulltype>
    System.out.println("Valid");
}
else if (a==2 && b !=null){
    System.out.println("Valid");
}
//and more
else{
    System.out.println("Invalid");
}
}
```

because user can key in optional so I need to check the train is exist in order to process booking 
Is something wrong with my code or just this is impossible to be done in Java?

Comment: What is `b`? It seems to be an `int`. Can primitives be `null`?

Comment: If `b` is an `int`, it can never be `null`... Show more code

Comment: I'm not even sure what you're trying to accomplish with the comparison.  Seeing `b` defined would be nice, although it's been well established here that primitive types cannot be `null`.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanilos: in my concept b is from previous method, is int too but is key in previously so need to check for make sure the value is exist

Comment: @fge: I declared b is int too but is in previous method and key in by user and back to my main in order to process i need to check weather both value are exist or not

Comment: what do you mean by "make sure the value is exist" ?

Comment: ensure that user previously have key in a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what `null` means. `null` doesn't refer to a value, but to a reference (Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2707333/3457753) answer for more info about it). The bottom line is that the only things that can reference `null` are complex types, like `String`s, `Integer`s, classes you define, etc. Primitive types (`int`s, `boolean`s, etc.) are not references, so can never reference `null`

Comment: so what if I need to find out is the int value exist or not, if cannot use null what should i use for replace it?

Comment: You're giving `a` and `b` values from user input, right? Why not do a check then to make sure that they've entered two values? I'm not sure how you're getting your user input, but I would suggest reading about the [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class and [Anupam's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22896797/3457753) to give you some ideas

Comment: yes, I used 'Scanner' for getting input, but 'b' is get from previous method and is optional so now in new method I need both 'a' and 'b' exist so I try to find out is user insert any value in 'b'

Comment: There's no way to do that with primitives in Java. one thing you could do is make `b` an `Integer` rather than an `int`; `b` would then be a non-primitive types, which could reference `null`. Another option would be some additional meta-data (a `boolean`, for examples), that tells you if this optional parameter has been set

Comment: I have change b to Integer and now my error is gone =D 
Thanks for help me out

Answer (score 2):

An `int`  can never be null as it is a primitive data type, hence `b !=null` is uncomputable.

If you are using the Scanner class's `nextInt()` command, this will always return an integer value (or cause a runtime exception if the user does not enter an int)

Answer (score 1):

The type of `b` is `int`, and `int` variables cannot be `null` by definition.

If you need to be able to store `null` in `b`, one possibility would be to change its type to [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html?is-external=true).

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to do a try catch, instead of this. Doing a try-catch will save you if user enters a string or null.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
try
{
    int a = sc.nextInt();
    int b = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("valid numbers");
}
catch(InputMismatchException ex)
{
    System.out.println("Invalid numbers");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change `int` to object type `Integer`. Then you can compare it to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

An int connot be null because it's a primitive type. Therefore checking b for null is totally wrong, if we correct your code, it will be like this :

```
if (a==1 || a==2){
    System.out.println("Valid");
}
else{
    System.out.println("Invalid");
}
```

Comment: but in my case I need to check is any value in b to process

Comment: MorganSlm you have to understand that an int has always a value, by default this value is a 0.

Answer (score -3):

if b is supposed to be an int you could try

```
if (a==1 && b instanceof int)
```

Comment: If it is a primitive, it is not an instance.