# Android Error creating java class and using it

Tags: java, android

Im trying to do a simple application in android with a new class for learn how to use it. The main activity have :

```
package com.josejoaquin.testhttp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    Button Boton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    TextView Texto = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    Boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            clientehttp clienteweb = null;
            String total;
            total = clienteweb.getWeb();
            Texto.setText(total);

        }
    });


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

And the other file is named clientehtt.java and have this code:

```
package com.josejoaquin.testhttp;


public class clientehttp {

   public String getWeb (){

    String texto ="Hola Mundo";
    return texto;


}
}
```

THe manifiest file have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.josejoaquin.testhttp" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

But i get and error when i do a click the applition close, what im doing wrong? Can anyone help me to learn more about this?

Best Regards.

Comment: So what's the error? Please post the LogCat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you get a `NullPointerException`.

The problem is inside your `onClick()` method:

```
        clientehttp clienteweb = null;
        String total;
        total = clienteweb.getWeb();
```

You are setting the value of `clienteweb` to `null` but you are then attempting to use its method `clienteweb.getWeb()` and you cannot do that.

Change your code to:

```
        clientehttp clienteweb = new clientehttp();
        String total;
        total = clienteweb.getWeb();
```

and everything should work. If you are wondering what exactly was wrong, think about `null` meaning `empty` or `nothing`. If your `clienteweb` is empty, it pretty much doesn't exist yet and thus doesn't have any methods such as `getWeb()` for you to call.

So the statement:

```
clientehttp clienteweb = null;
```

Loosely means "I declare a variable of type `clientehttp` and initialize it to nothing"

Once you instantiate it (with the `new` expression), then it becomes "filled" and you can use its methods. For more info you should [read up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2707333/3928341) on what `null` is and how java [declares/instantiates/initializes](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~daeron/docs/javaguide/java/anatomy/creating.html) objects.

Also, you should probably use Java's standard naming conventions to make your code cleaner.
One specific convention you should add is to name all your classes with a starting capital letter (If you are using Eclipse it probably already warns you to do that)

So rename the class `clientehttp` to `Clientehttp` so its clearer that it is a class. The easiest way to do that is to right-click on the `clientehttp.java` and do Refractor/Rename and the change will be applied everywhere.

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm but i didnt understand why to put new clientehttp() if im creating a new variable of this type.

Comment: @user1532116 well that's exactly why. You use the `new` expression to create a new object. You are welcome :) Read the links I posted in my answer for more info.