# Comparing two nulls, getting NullPointerException

Tags: java

I'm trying to get two nulls to compare, keeps throwing java.lang.NullPointerException in Eclipse

```
public Double x(String x){

        if (x.split(" ")[1].equals("+")) {
            // Ignore this stuff, it works
            this.x = Double.valueOf(x.split(" ")[0]);
            return new Double(x(Double.valueOf(x.split(" ")[2])));
        } else if (x.split(" ")[1].equals("x")) {
            // Ignore this stuff, it works
            this.x = Double.valueOf(x.split(" ")[0]);
            return new Double(x(Double.parseDouble(x.split(" ")[2])));
        } else {
            // The problem
            return new Double(null);
        }
    }

public boolean testParser() {

    boolean parseOne;
    boolean parseTwo;
    boolean parseThree;

        if (calc.x("12 + 5") == 17) {
            System.out.println("[ OK ] Parser adds correctly.");
            parseOne = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("[FAIL] Basic parsing fails to add.");
            parseOne = false;
        }
        if (calc.x("12 x 5") == 60) {
            System.out.println("[ OK ] Parser multiplies correctly.");
            parseTwo = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("[FAIL] Basic parsing fails to multiply.");
            parseTwo = false;
        }

        // Comparing null with null here not working
        if (calc.x("12 [ 3") == null) {
            System.out.println("[ OK ] Parser returns null for operators which are not supported.");
            parseThree = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("[FAIL] Parser does not return null for operators which are not supported.");
            parseThree = false;
        }

        return (parseOne && parseTwo && parseThree);    
    }
```

(Where calc is just the name of an instance of an object which the Double x(String x) method is in)
Can anyone suggest a way to resolve this?

Comment: This `new Double(null)` is not a `null`.

Comment: [What is null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java)

Comment: [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Not related to problem but: don't add [Java] in your title, you already tagged your question with `Java`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what `new Double(null)` does...

The compiler has to find a constructor that matches.  There are two constructors for the `Double` class (according to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html)):

```
Double(double value)
    // Constructs a newly allocated Double object that represents the primitive double argument.
Double(String s)
    // Constructs a newly allocated Double object that represents the floating-point value of type double represented by the string.
```

`null` is not a valid value for a primitive type (i.e. small-d `double`), so this results in an attempt to call the second constructor, that takes a `String`.  At runtime, it then tries to parse the string in the format of a `double`.  And this results in a `NullPointerException` because the `String` parameter is null.  [To be more precise, I think at some point there will be a call to `s.trim()` from the class `sun.misc.FloatingDecimal`, which throws an exception if `s` is `null`.]

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the null pointer exception because you are calling

```
new Double(null);
```

This is not how you use the Double constructor. To pass back null, simply return null. You can fix this by changing this line to:

```
return null;
```