# Is null typed in Java

Tags: java, types, null

I've encountered a bug in my codebase, I've narrowed down to what caused this behavior. The first test case fails, whereas the last two succeed.

```
@Test
public void testBooleanNull1() {
    Boolean nullB = null;
    assertFalse(Boolean.valueOf(nullB));
}

@Test
public void testBooleanNull2() {
    String nullS = null;
    assertFalse(Boolean.valueOf(nullS));
}
@Test
public void testBooleanNull3() {
    assertFalse(Boolean.valueOf(null));
}
```

I know that `Boolean.valueOf` is an overloaded method with two variants one takes a `String` and the other takes a primitive of type `boolean`.

I suspect that this is happening because of auto-boxing but I'm not sure if that is the case, furthermore I don't know why `null` is being converted to a `Boolean` as far as I know `null` is not a valid `primitive` type.

I've moved on to using `BooleanUtils` from `Apache Commons`, I asked this here to better understand why the behavior is this way.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This

```
Boolean.valueOf(nullB)
```

is an invocation of [`Boolean#valueOf(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf%28boolean%29).

It fails because the unboxing of the `Boolean` value `nullB` fails with a `NullPointerException`. In other words, it becomes

```
boolean val = nullB.booleanValue(); // at runtime nullB stores the value null
Boolean.valueOf(val)
```

This process is described in the JLS [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)

> If `r` is a reference of type `Boolean`, then unboxing conversion converts
>   `r` into `r.booleanValue()`

This

```
Boolean.valueOf(null)
```

is invoking the [overloaded version that accepts a `String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) (since [`null`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1) is not a valid expression of type `boolean`).

> Returns a `Boolean` with a value represented by the specified string.
>   The Boolean returned represents a `true` value if the string argument is
>   not `null` and is equal, ignoring case, to the string `"true"`.

Answer (score 5):

Overloaded method resolution is described in JLS:

> 15.12.2. Compile-Time Step 2: Determine Method Signature
>
> ...
>
> 1. The first phase (§15.12.2.2) performs overload resolution without permitting boxing or unboxing conversion, or the use of variable arity method invocation. If no applicable method is found during this phase then processing continues to the second phase.

In our case, choosing between `Boolean.valueOf(boolean)` and `Boolean.valueOf(String)` compiler chooses `valueOf(String)` because it does not required unboxing.

Comment: This answer hits the nail on the head!

Answer (score 2):

Taking a look at the source code of class `Boolean`

```
public static Boolean valueOf(String s) {
    return toBoolean(s) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

.. and then:

```
private static boolean toBoolean(String name) {
   return ((name != null) && name.equalsIgnoreCase("true"));
}
```

If the String argument is `null` for `Boolean.valueOf(String s)`, it will return false, hence the second case succeeds.

In the first case, on the use of Boolean.valueOf which takes the data type as boolean, here is what the documentation states:

```
public static Boolean valueOf(boolean b)

Returns a Boolean instance representing the specified boolean value. If the specified boolean value is true, this method returns Boolean.TRUE; if it is false, this method returns Boolean.FALSE. If a new Boolean instance is not required, this method should generally be used in preference to the constructor Boolean(boolean), as this method is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance.

Parameters:
b - a boolean value.
Returns:
a Boolean instance representing b.
```

The parameter required here is a `boolean` value which accepts `True` or `False` and not `Boolean` value which accepts `True` , `False` or `null`. Since you passed a `Boolean` value and not `boolean` value, I guess that's the reason it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Why the second one will succeed? Look at the doc of [`public static Boolean valueOf(String s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29):

> Returns a Boolean with a value represented by the specified string. 
>       The Boolean returned represents a true value if the string argument is **not null** and is equal, ignoring case, to the string "true".

You passed a `null` in, so it will return `false`.