# how does "null" works ? is its value a constant?

Tags: java

Can someone tell the binary value for null? I know its **JVM** dependent but can someone tell me how it actually works ? How does JVM allocate a address for null?
Does it stays constant throughout until system restarts?

Comment: I think there is no way to find the value for null. But this may help you to know what null exactly is. [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java)

Comment: Have a look. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java

Comment: Why would you want to know? It's not possible to ever use this knowledge, as a Java program cannot gain access to the representation of a pointer in Java. It's only useful when you want to debug a JVM, and since you don't think it's important to mention which JVM you want to know this for, you're probably not going to do that.

Comment: The most straightforward implementation of `null` is indeed to set it to a fixed and known invalid address. I would expect most JVMs to follow this pattern (if only because C does it too) but you never know until you look.

Comment: to be honest handling null and JVM or C driven JVM thing or C itself is no wonder.Because , those are driven form C itself except Java added it own high level abstraction to manage thing like memory! so null is pointer in C and Java but manager on later! Adios!

Answer (score 0):

'Null' in java or most often in programming language with empty initialization who don't have nulls consume a memory space.It does refer to a variable who value is pointing to a null value but created in memory.

For Example:

```
String nullString = null ; declares 16 byte memory but point to null value.
```

Even Though u mean null memory is used to reference the variable in this case nullString later.

**Let say you wanna

```
String nullString = "10"; 

//still this time consumes the same 
 bytes because it already declared but value pointer is changed this time!**
```

To be honest handling null and JVM or C driven JVM thing or C itself is no wonder.Because , those are driven form C itself except Java added it own high level abstraction to manage thing like memory! so null is pointer in C and Java but manager on later! Adios!

Comment: "null**String** = 10;" ??

Comment: nullString=10 didn't get it

Comment: Let say a varible you declare called String nullString = 10; //assigned

Comment: @danielad You declare a variable of type `String` and assign an `int` literal to it?

Comment: oh man that is right just a focusing on memory part that is correct!