# Difference between an empty ArrayList and an ArrayList with null elements?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, null

I am coding some validators for a REST service which parse a JSON and I found out something that sounds wierd for me (I am not a ***JAVA expert*** at all).

Consider having two ***ArrayLists***:

```
ArrayList<Object> list1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
ArrayList<Object> list2 = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Both lists have something in ***common***: they are *completely empty* (or full of null elements). But if I do:

```
list1.add(null);
```

Although both remain completely ***empty***, *they have completely different behaviors*. And to make some methods the results are ***very different***:

```
System.out.println(list1.contains(null));  //prints true!
System.out.println(list2.contains(null));  //prints false

System.out.println(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(list1));  //prints true
System.out.println(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(list2));  //prints false

System.out.println(list1.size());  //prints 1
System.out.println(list2.size());  //prints 0
```

Doing some research, and looking at the implementation of each of these methods, you can determine the reason for these differences, but still do not understand why it would be valid or useful to differentiate between these lists.

- Why ***add(item)*** doesnt validate if **item!=null** ?
- Why ***contains(null)*** says **false** if the list is full of **nulls**?

Thanks in advance!!!

***EDIT:***

I am mostly agree whit the answers, but I'm not yet convinced all. This is the implementation of the method remove:

```
/**
 * Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list,
 * if it is present.  If the list does not contain the element, it is
 * unchanged.  More formally, removes the element with the lowest index
 * <tt>i</tt> such that
 * <tt>(o==null&nbsp;?&nbsp;get(i)==null&nbsp;:&nbsp;o.equals(get(i)))</tt>
 * (if such an element exists).  Returns <tt>true</tt> if this list
 * contained the specified element (or equivalently, if this list
 * changed as a result of the call).
 *
 * @param o element to be removed from this list, if present
 * @return <tt>true</tt> if this list contained the specified element
 */
public boolean remove(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
            if (elementData[index] == null) {
                fastRemove(index);
                return true;
            }
    } else {
        for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
            if (o.equals(elementData[index])) {
                fastRemove(index);
                return true;
            }
    }
    return false;
}


/*
 * Private remove method that skips bounds checking and does not
 * return the value removed.
 */
private void fastRemove(int index) {
    modCount++;
    int numMoved = size - index - 1;
    if (numMoved > 0)
        System.arraycopy(elementData, index+1, elementData, index,
                         numMoved);
    elementData[--size] = null; // clear to let GC do its work
}
```

So, now if i do:

```
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
list.add(null);
System.out.println(list.contains(null)); //prints true!
list.remove(null);
System.out.println(list.contains(null));  //prints false!
```

***what I'm missing?***

Comment: Java collections allow for null elements. This is a design decision you'll have to live with (or choose a different collections framework).

Comment: You would need to understand what null is:
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java

Comment: Given only the lines of code you have shown, `list2.size()` should print `0`, not `2`. Is that a mistake in the comment or are there lines of code you didn't show?

Comment: To say `list2` _is full of nulls_ is incorrect. `list2` doesn't contain anything, not even a single `null` element.

Comment: When I run your second program, the second `System.out.println` prints `false`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman thanks for the comment, i already fix this!

Answer (score 13):

A list containing `null` is **NOT** *empty*.  It contains `null`.  Lists are allowed to contain null, so you can put null in it if you want.

Comment: Ok! Thats right, i agree with you. But, whats the difference between list 1 and 2?

Comment: "*Lists are allowed to contain null*" can be misleading since there is no guarantee that *all* list do so. But it is true in case of `ArrayList`.

Comment: @melli-182 The difference is one is empty, and one has *something* (a `null`) in it.  Write a loop to print out the elements and you'll see that one executes the loop body zero times with no output and one executes one time with one line of output. One of them will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception if you try to `.get(0)` and the other will return to you the `null` value that is at index 0.

Answer (score 3):

An `ArrayList` explicitly is allowed and able to store `null` values, because they might be meaningful to your program. And empty list is empty (i.e. doesn't contain anything, not even `null`. After you successfully [add](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29)(null) (it returns `true` to signal success), the list must obviously return `true` on [contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)(null) as well. In fact, you can even [remove](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29)(null) from that list and it will be empty again.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately you don't have to be a java expert or an expert at all.

The best way to think of this is like a parking lot.  An array with null elements is like a parking lot with nothing parked in it.  An empty array is like the plans for a parking lot.

Answer (score 0):

A `List` is empty if it contains zero elements.  This is both the natural meaning of the term and the test performed by the `isEmpty()` method.

`null` is a value that any `ArrayList` may contain as an element.  Clearly, in that case the list has at least one element, and therefore is not empty.  No matter what the initial state of a `List`, if an invocation of `add(null)` on that list completes normally then afterward the list is not empty.  Similarly, each `null` element in a list contributes to its size.

> Why `add(item)` doesnt validate if `item!=null` ?

Ask [Joshua Bloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Bloch).  He designed it.  Most people take him to be a pretty smart guy, and consider the Collections API a highly successful effort.

Seriously, it is a design choice that `List`s may contain `null` elements. (Implementations are permitted to reject nulls, but `ArrayList`, as a general-purpose implementation, accepts them).

> Why contains(null) says false if the list is full of nulls?

It doesn't.  Don't just take my word for it -- the data you present also contradict you.

Answer (score 0):

The entire confusion stems from the incorrect initial assumption that the ArrayLists you created are full of nulls. They are not, they are **completely empty** - meaning they have **zero elements**. As such, you will get **false** if you call `contains(null)`on them, and **true** when you call `isEmpty()`.

Once you added null to list1, it ceased to be empty, and indeed contains a null element - **list2 is still empty and still doesn't contain null**.

In your last code sample, the second call to Collections.isNotEmpty **definitely does not return true**. The list had one null element, you removed it, so it's empty again.

The main take-aways here are:

- **Calling either the empty constructor, or the constructor with initial capacity of an ArrayList creates an empty list**. This list does not contain **any elements, not even null**.
- **null is a perfectly valid element of an ArrayList**. The cases where this might be useful are not extremely common but they do exist.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in the List **size**, not its **capacity**. When instantiating a new `ArrayList<>(5)`, the initial **capacity** is set to **5**, but the **size** remains **0**, because we haven't added any elements. If we invoke `add(null)` only the elements `size()` will increase and all functions iterating through the array of elements will remain inbetween the **size** of the List, not the **capacity**.

This is so when we need to rapidly add new elements, the array doesn't get copied into another array with a size + 1, instead Java increases the *capacity* by half when the *size* is equal to it to improve the performance by reducing the functions performed.