# What is null's value?

Tags: java, null, terminology

I know what `null` is.

I know `null` means to "cancel out" make it zero, nothing, absolutely blank.

But if null is a variable, what is it's value? It has to have an initialised value, correct?

Comment: `null` is the **opposite** of a value, it is used to indicate **not a value** and is a constant managed by the JVM.

Comment: Question closed as a duplicate. In the future, please search first as this question has been asked/answered many times: [links to similar questions](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java+what+is+null+site:http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F).

Comment: null has no value. It's meaning has been well discussed and well answered. Please read the first several hits in the link.

Comment: `null` is not a variable. It is a possible, opaque, value of a reference-typed variable. One might expect it to be zero-valued, but there is no possible way of observing it from pure Java code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels `null` *is* a value, and it's the only value of the null type. See 3.10.7 of the JLS: "The null type has one value, the null reference, represented by the null literal null, which is formed from ASCII characters."

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt: thanks, I had not known that. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> But if null is a variable, what is it's value?

null cannot **be** a variable, but rather it is the value held by a reference variable that refers to nothing.

> It has to have an initialised value, correct?

Per the JVM, it is the initialized value of any non-initialized reference field.

Better answer to be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java). Closing question as a duplicate.