# Java: Can you treat null like integer 0 like in C?

Tags: java, pointers, null

I want to check how many fields of an object are null. Can I do something like:

```
int numNotNull = !!(obj.a) + !!(obj.b) + !!(obj.c) + !!(obj.d);
```

This would work if null was a pointer to the 0 address, as in C.

Comment: No, you can't. You'd have to do `obj.a != null ? 1 : 0` for each of the checks.

Comment: No, you can not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a good understanding of what `null` is in Java, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2707333/4822566). The major point of discussion is that as well as being a keyword referring to the `null` value, the type of that value is the nameless type 'null':

> There is also a special null type, the type of the expression null,
>   which has no name. Because the null type has no name, it is impossible
>   to declare a variable of the null type or to cast to the null type.
>   The null reference is the only possible value of an expression of null
>   type. The null reference can always be cast to any reference type. In
>   practice, the programmer can ignore the null type and just pretend
>   that null is merely a special literal that can be of any reference
>   type.

Hence the inability to use it directly in numerical calculations - it's a type mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer which is already accepted now, explains what `null` means in Java.

However if your original goal was to get the count of the null fields in one liner code, you can do it the following way:

```
int numNotNull = (((numNotNull = 0) == 0 && obj.a == null && ++numNotNull < 0) || (obj.b == null && ++numNotNull < 0) || (obj.c == null && ++numNotNull < 0) || (obj.d == null && ++numNotNull < 0)) ? 0 : numNotNull;
```