# Codename one:Application close unfortunately

Tags: codenameone, mobile-application

When ever I moved from one form to another form the application close and I got the error"Application close unfortunately" and got below error in log file
"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.codename1.impl.android.InPlaceEditView$EditView.switchToTextArea(com.codename1.ui.TextArea)' on a null object reference"
can you help me to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is null in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Connect your device with a cable and look at the logcat/DDMS output. Provide us with the exact stack trace of the error in the [issue tracker](http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/).

Comment: did same think got below error "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.codename1.impl.android.InPlaceEditView$EditView.switchToTextArea(com.codename1.ui.TextArea)"

Comment: Without the stack trace this is useless. Connect the device with a cable and use DDMS or logcat to produce a stack trace of the error