# Best way to check if a reference is null in Java

Tags: java

I was wondring what the best way to check if we have a valid reference in java. I know that this syntax works, but its a mouth full.

```
if (myObj == null) {
  // Do something knowing we have an object
}
```

I'm coming from some other languages that allow you to just check a pointer like in c++.

```
char* prt = null;
if (ptr) {
  // We know we have a valid c-string 
}
```

Is there any equivocate or similar syntax in java? I would be okay using compiler extensions or a preprocessor.

Follow up before. Before some one jumps in a starts talking about why I should just use the java syntax because you can forget an `=` sign please don't.

```
if (myObj = null)
```

Will be caught by the compiler/linter.

Comment: Also there a quite a few values that would be considered "invalid" in other languages. Such as `0` or `false` or `""`. In Java you have to define exactly what is considered valid yourself.

Comment: `null` is idiomatic and makes for easy reading. The fact that C uses `0x0` is implementation detail IMO.

Comment: this will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2707333/2724879

Comment: @Basti  `myObject.equals(null)` could never return `true` -- it would NPE.

Comment: @slim "could never" -> "should never". A badly overwritten `equals` method could allow `null`. I for example saw a JSON lib (can't remember which one) which said that JSON value `"null"` is equal to `null` ... sadly.

Answer (score 6):

Alas Java does not have an implicit conversion of the analogue of a `nullptr_t` or a pointer type to `bool`, so you have to use the somewhat more long-winded notation

`if (myObj == null)`

whereas in C++ we can write

`if (myObj)`

In this respect, Java is less terse, and arguably clearer.

Answer (score 5):

There is no shortcut syntax for dealing with `null` checks in Java, not even a null coalesce or null propagation operators available in other languages. There are no user-defined conversion operators either, so you wouldn't be able to use the C++ idiom that lets you write loops on expressions returning objects, e.g. `while (cin >> x) { ... }`.

However, a powerful alternative exists in Java 8 to avoid `null` checks altogether: wrap your nullable objects in [`Optional<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html), and use its methods to hide null checks.

Here is a short example:

```
String s = "Hello";
Optional<String> os = Optional.ofNullable(s);
os.ifPresent(x -> { System.out.println(x); });
```

The above [prints](https://ideone.com/aOb12X) `"Hello"`. If you set `s` to `null`, the code would print nothing.

[Oracle's article on using `Optional<T>`.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html)

Comment: Great if there's an API between the `Optional` being initiated, and its consumer calling its methods. But don't use `Optional.ofNullable(x).ifPresent(...)` when `if(x==null) { ... }` will do.

Comment: @slim Ah, of course not! I don't like an idea of swatting flies with a sledgehammer, no matter how efficient it may be at killing the flies.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(x == null) {
    doSomething();
}
```

... is the general idiom in Java. Java's designers made the decision not to allow treating non-boolean variables as implicit "truthy" values.

Another common idiom is to use `x == null` in a ternary statement:

```
return x == null ? "not found" : x;
```

Or to use a standard method to throw an exception early on nulls:

```
Objects.requireNonNull(x);
```

---

More generally, try to adopt a programming style in which you never expect null to be passed, and therefore don't have to code for the possibility.

On non-public APIs, since you never pass a null, you never need to test for null (if a `NullPointerException` occurs, whoever passed the null can take responsibility for the mess themselves).

In public APIs, it may be a courtesy to the caller to validate non-nulls at the point they are passed, but it's by no means essential in every case.

A reasonable goal is to always expect inputs to be non-null, and to never return a null (since Java 8, use `Optional` instead if necessary, or adopt the [Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern)).

Comment: Amen to the practice of not using or expecting nulls in the first place.