# What is the difference between String str=null and String str="null"?

Tags: java, string, null

I have a class with the two string variable i.e:

```
String str = null;
String str1="null";
```

One is a "string value null" and other in other case null object is assigned to a string variable.
So what is the difference in both the two assignments and how to check if one is different from other ??

Comment: "null" is a string with the word "null" in it, which is entirely different from a null value.

Comment: [What is null in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2707322)

Answer (score 7):

`String str = null;`  means str is a reference of String which points to null.

And `String str1="null";` means str1 object which points to String Object which is "null".

First check if object is null or not ? then compare by using equals method.
like

```
if(str==null && str1==null){
   //Both are null and equal
}   

if(str != null && str.equals(str1)){
  //return true;
}
else
{
   //return false;
}
```

Comment: by using `equals` method .  first check that if object is not null then compare by `equals()` method of `String`

Comment: Yes, that should be part of your answer, since it was in OP's question. :)

Comment: you could simplify `str!=null && str1!=null&& str.equals(str1)` to `str != null && str.equals(str1)`

Answer (score 3):

The String `"null"` is a string of length 4 with the characters `n`, `u`, `l` and `l`. It can be worked on as any other string.

The `null` reference isn't a string. Any attempt to use it like a string will result in a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

1)    String str = null;

Here str has no instance is created because it is assigned to null, so no new memory is consumed in heap

2)   String str1="null";

Here str1 string instance is created and "null" is stored as value