# What is the difference between null and isEmpty?

Tags: android

I want to get to know what is the difference between null and isEmpty(). Are those 2 are same or different.

Comment: Of which class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, null and isEmpty() is different.

This is a simple explanation of the difference:

Let's take an example of a String.

Null means that your object (String) is not instantiated yet. It's still pointing to nothing. While isEmpty() is a method to check if a String contains no character.

You can try to make 2 different String objects, where one String defines as a null, while the other one is empty, as below.

```
String nullString = null;
String emptyString = "";

try {
    System.out.println(nullString); // will produce NullPointerException
    nullString.isEmpty(); // will produce NullPointerException
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    System.out.println(emptyString); // OUTPUT:  (empty)
    emptyString.isEmpty(); // OUTPUT: true
}
```

I hope it's clear. 
-CMIIW-

Answer (score 0):

Supposing we have a string variable "s" whose value is null,

```
s == null and s.isEmpty()
```

will give you two different responses ie.,

```
s == null
```

will give the output **"true"**

And

```
s.isEmpty()
```

will give you the output **"NullPointerException"**

Alternatively, if the string s="" then,

**s == null** will give you the output **"false"**
and **s.isEmpty()** will give you the output **"true"**

Any other string value for the variable "s" like **s="java"** would result in both **s == null** and **s.isEmpty()** resulting in the output **"false"**

Answer (score 0):

You can think about it like this:

**isEmpty()** - returns boolean (true/false) in accordance of the length of something.

**null** - null is nothing,  it is not an instance of anything and it won't return true/false if something is empty.

For more info, you can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java).