# Unable to fetch response time for prev.getParent().getStartTime() in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jsr223

I'm trying the get the response time for the complete test case (All transactions) in JMeter. I'll be using it for calculating pacing using
[JSR223 Timer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eXEe.png)

I am able to get time for single sample using `prev.getTime()` but when I use `prev.getParent().getTime()`, I don't see anything in logs and script doesn't halt for pacing.

I have also tried placing the timer at a different level (Scope of thread group) still nothing. Where I am going wrong here?

Thanks,
Sachin

Answer (score 0):

[`prev.getParent()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#getParent--) function is applicable for **subresults** for example when the Sampler is a child of a [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller).

If you have a single Sampler somewhere in Thread Group it will not have any parent hence your function will fail with the [NPE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html).

You can work it around by introducing checking this `getParent()` for [`null`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java) like:

```
def time = 0
if (prev.getParent() != null) {
    time = prev.getParent().getTime()
} 
else {
    time = prev.getTime()
}
```

Check out [How to Easily Implement Pacing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-easily-implement-pacing-jmeter/) article for more comprehensive information if needed.

Comment: @Dmitri T - Thanks for your help. I figured out "Generate Parent Sample" was not checked so i couldnt get the transaction time. But to get the iteration time (All transaction combined) in a variable is not working for me. prev.getParent() updates time for each transaction and hence couldn't fetch it.