# NullPointerException for similar of System.out.println

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null

I was checking System.out.println to understand composition of Java and i tried to make a similar of it like this;

FakeSystem class

```
public class FakeSystem {
public final static Print out = null;
}
```

Print class

```
public class Print {
public void print(String text){
    System.out.println(text);
 }
}
```

Main class

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FakeSystem.out.print("my text");
 }
}
```

It gives NullPointerException when i do this but it has null when i check "out" variable of original System class at java.lang package. It gives "my text" output when i change "out" variable to this;

```
public final static Print out = new Print();
```

I wanna understand why doesn't it work when i make it null.

Comment: Please read this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java). null means your field doesn't point to an actual object. How do you expect to call a method on a nonexistent value?

Comment: but original out variable of System class is like - PrintStream out = null;

Comment: It is later set to something else, depending on where your code executes

Comment: In FakeSystem class initialize the Print object as Print out = new Print();

Comment: @ChitraveerAkhil Yeah, the OP did that, they were just wondering why setting it to null worked in java.lang.System but not in their own class

Comment: @krystal If you go to the source code (https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/System.java) you'll see there's a static block that looks like `static { registerNatives(); }`. I'm fairly certain that's where `out` is set

Comment: @user oh thank you, i didnt think of it is later set to something else.