# How to extract a value from encrypted-decrypted reponse using json extractor in jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter, base64, decode, jmeter-5.0

I have already tried with this below code but it is showing Caused by:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getValue() on null object
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:324) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:72) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:223) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.extractor.JSR223PostProcessor.process(JSR223PostProcessor.java:44) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPostProcessors(JMeterThread.java:925) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:564) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_202]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method setValue() on null object
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:47) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:34) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.purestudy.encryption.Script77.run(Script77.groovy:32) ~[?:?]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:321) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method setValue() on null object
```

This is the  code i have implemented but it is only accepting for the arguments passed and encrypted with jsr223 preproccessor in bodydata but not working for which wecan't apply preproccessor & this is written jsr223 post proccessor

```
 **String encryptedText= "${ENCRYPTEDResponseofprevREQ}";
   log.info(encryptedText);

   String decryptedText = new OpenSSLEncryptDecrypt().decrypt(encryptedText);
   log.info(decryptedText);

   ctx.getCurrentSampler().getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue(decryptedText);

   vars.put("variable",decryptedText);
   def my_var1 = vars.get("variable");
  
   log.info(my_var1);
   ctx.getCurrentSampler().getArguments().getArgument(0).setValue(my_var1);**
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
ctx.getCurrentSampler().getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue(decryptedText);
```

causes the error because `ctx.getCurrentSampler().getArguments().getArgument(0)` returns [null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java) and you're trying to invoke `getValue()` function on a null object.

Demo:

[image]

It's hard to say how to fix the issue without knowing what you're trying to achieve, but 2 things are obvious:

1. Your HTTP Request sampler doesn't have arguments - that's why you're getting this error
2. There is no such a function `getValue(String)`, the function [`getValue()` takes no parameters](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/config/Argument.html#getValue--)

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter

Answer (score 0):

Yes in http request there are no arguments I need the code to extract the value from that sampler which is encrypted to store in the next sampler Dmitri T