# How to resolve "Cannot invoke method contains() on null object"

Tags: jmeter

In my script I am trying to make a get call and asserting on the response. This is working fine with valid response but for invalid response I am trying to fetch the UUID of the request URL but not working.

**Request URL:**

http://localhost:8080/log/log-events/6cef99be-591e-42e4-b07c-34b45f9540df

**Response incase of failure:**

```
{"trace-id":"8000043e-0001-eb00-b63f-84710c7967bb","invalid-param":[],"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.4","title":"The specified resource was not found.","status":404,"detail":"Resource not found","instance":"/log-events/6cef99be-591e-42e4-b07c-34b45f9540df"}
```

**Assertion Script:**

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

def failureMessage = "";
def jsonResponse = null;

JsonSlurper JSON = new JsonSlurper();

try {
  jsonResponse = JSON.parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString());
  customerID = jsonResponse.customerId
} catch (Exception e) {
  def requestData = sampler.getUrl().toString();
  def pattern = Pattern.compile('^http?://localhost:8080/log/log-events/([^/]+)/.*$')
  def (_, refDATA) = (requestData =~ pattern)[0]
  failureMessage += refDATA
}
if (customerID.contains("Test") ||customerID.contains('KENDLE') || customerID.contains('CLINIRX') || customerID.contains('GSK')) {
  AssertionResult.setFailure(false);
} else {
        AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
        AssertionResult.setFailureMessage(failureMessage);

}
```

**Error message details:**

```
2021-08-13 10:40:21,803 ERROR o.a.j.a.JSR223Assertion: Problem in JSR223 script: ClientID_Validator
javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method contains() on null object
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:71) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:222) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.assertions.JSR223Assertion.getResult(JSR223Assertion.java:50) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processAssertion(JMeterThread.java:916) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.checkAssertions(JMeterThread.java:885) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:573) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_251]
```

Just wanted to print the UUID:`6cef99be-591e-42e4-b07c-34b45f9540df` incase of failure

What I missed here?

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see any `customerId` object in your JSON response hence your line `customerID = jsonResponse.customerId` returns [null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java) and when later on you're trying to call `customerID.contains()` function it fails because `customerID` is null.

Without seeing successful response and not knowing what you're trying to achieve in case of success it's hard to advice anything meaningful, as a workaround you can add an extra check for the `customerID` like:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

import java.util.regex.Pattern

def failureMessage = "";
def jsonResponse = null;

JsonSlurper JSON = new JsonSlurper();

try {
    jsonResponse = JSON.parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString());
    customerID = jsonResponse.customerId
} catch (Exception e) {
    def requestData = sampler.getUrl().toString();
    def pattern = Pattern.compile('^http?://localhost:8080/log/log-events/([^/]+)/.*$')
    def (_, refDATA) = (requestData =~ pattern)[0]
    failureMessage += refDATA
}
if (customerID != null) {
    if (customerID.contains("Test") || customerID.contains('KENDLE') || customerID.contains('CLINIRX') || customerID.contains('GSK')) {
        AssertionResult.setFailure(false);
    } else {
        AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
        AssertionResult.setFailureMessage(failureMessage);

    }
}
```

More information on using JSR223 Assertions: [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

You can split the URL and get the last item in the list.
Here is  a sample code to extract the UUID from the URL

```
def requestData ="http://localhost:8080/log/log-events/6cef99be-591e-42e4-b07c-34b45f9540df"

def uuid = requestData.split("/").last()

println "uuid = $uuid"
```