# Java - is `null` an instance of `object`?

Tags: java

I read that `null` isn't an `instanceof` anything, but on the other hand that **everything** in Java extends `Object` class.

Comment: Primitive types (`int`, `bool`, etc.) aren't subtypes of `Object`.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519631/is-null-a-java-keyword

Answer (score 60, accepted):

No, it is a `reference`. null is not an object

```
String s = null;

System.out.println(s instanceof Object); // false
```

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr `String s = "";` references a String object whose inner content (a char array) is empty. In the other hand, `String s = null` isn't referencing anything.

Comment: @HudsonPenaMagalhães So what? It may not reference anything 'real' but instead point to nothing, but it's a reference nonetheless.

Answer (score 11):

In a word, no.

Peter Norvig's [Java IAQ](http://norvig.com/java-iaq.html) addresses this question in some detail (specifically "[Q: Is null an Object?](http://norvig.com/java-iaq.html#null)")

Comment: Thanks for the great reference, which I was unaware of.

Comment: just had a quick look and there is actually an anchor that jumps straight to the relevant answer in the IAQ so I've updated your link

Answer (score 5):

> There is also a special null type, the
>   type of the expression null, which has
>   no name. Because the null type has no
>   name, it is impossible to declare a
>   variable of the null type or to cast
>   to the null type. The null reference
>   is the only possible value of an
>   expression of null type. The null
>   reference can always be cast to any
>   reference type. In practice, the
>   programmer can ignore the null type
>   and just pretend that null is merely a
>   special literal that can be of any
>   reference type

[Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/typesValues.doc.html)

Answer (score 3):

Null means that you don't have a reference to an object.

```
Object o = null;
```

o is a reference but there is no object referenced and no memory allocated for it.

```
o = new Object();
```

o is still a reference and holds the adress where the object is located in memory

Answer (score 2):

No, `null` is not an object. It is a literal that means that a variable does not reference any object.

Answer (score 1):

As the [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.1) says, `null` is of the null type and that is not a reference type. It is however usable in situations where a value of a reference type is expected (the value is really a “bottom” in the type algebra).

Answer (score 0):

Hoping that this example clears your doubt :

```
public void printObject(Object object) {
    System.out.println("object referred");
}

public void printObject(double[] doubleArray) {
    System.out.println("Array of type double");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JavaNullObjectTest javaNullObjectTest = new JavaNullObjectTest();

    javaNullObjectTest.printObject(null); //Array of type double

    javaNullObjectTest.printObject((Object)null); //object referred
}
```

We can but, convert a 'null' to object.