# Scanner.nextLine() not returning null?

Tags: java

I'm a student and I decided to try out some of the problem sets at UVa Online Judge to help improve my skill.  I ran into a brick wall on the first problem.  After fighting compiler errors (I *finally* found some vague guidelines for submitting Java code in their forums), I've now graduated to "Wrong Answer" status.

To get to the point -- if I don't surround this while loop with a try/catch, it generates a `NumberFormatException` at runtime on input string `""` on the call to `Integer.parseInt()`.  That makes sense, except if input is `""` then it is `null` and should not enter the loop.

I've tried getting rid of `split(" ")` and use a `StringTokenizer`, but that generates an wrong index exception.

The program works fine until I end input by hitting Enter.  That's when the error generates.  If I surround the loop with a try/catch, there's no errors, but the console seems to throw in an additional line break, and I believe that's the source of my "Wrong Answer" status.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
     Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
     String input;
     String[] temp;
     int i, j;

     while( (input = kb.nextLine()) != null ){
        temp = input.split(" ");
        i = Integer.parseInt(temp[0]);
        j = Integer.parseInt(temp[1]);
        solve(i, j);
     }
}
```

Comment: Empty String is not `null`...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802015/difference-between-null-and-java-string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is unclear why you're expecting `kb.nextLine()` to return `null` when an empty line is entered. You should compare against `""` instead of `null`.

You should also check `kb.hasNextLine()` before calling `kb.nextLine()`.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
     Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
     String[] temp;
     int i, j;

     while (kb.hasNextLine()) {
        String input = kb.nextLine();
        if (input.equals("")) break;
        temp = input.split(" ");
        i = Integer.parseInt(temp[0]);
        j = Integer.parseInt(temp[1]);
        solve(i, j);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you (and the rest of the responders).  A novice mistake on my part!

Answer (score 0):

There is a next line so it won't return `null` its just that the line is empty and thus `""`.