# Does java.util.List.isEmpty() check if the list itself is null?

Tags: java, list

Does `java.util.List.isEmpty()` check if the list itself is `null`, or do I have to do this check myself?

For example:

```
List<String> test = null;

if (!test.isEmpty()) {
    for (String o : test) {
        // do stuff here            
    }
}
```

Will this throw a `NullPointerException` because test is `null`?

Comment: It can't. An NPE would be thrown before it could be invoked.

Comment: This ("Will this throw a NullPointerException because test is null?") is actually a very wrongly formulated question. You can easily test this question via a very simple test. The question itself of course takes to considering deeper insight into how the references in Java work, why is Java designed so this is not possible, but then you should have asked differently.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

You're trying to call the `isEmpty()` method on a `null` reference (as `List test = null;`). This will surely throw a `NullPointerException`. You should do `if(test!=null)` instead (checking for `null` first).

The method `isEmpty()` returns true, if an `ArrayList` object contains no elements; false otherwise (for that the `List` must first be instantiated that is in your case is `null`).

You may want to see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802015/difference-between-null-and-java-string).

Answer (score 144):

I would recommend using [Apache Commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Commons) Collections:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#isEmpty-java.util.Collection-

which implements it quite ok and well documented:

```
/**
 * Null-safe check if the specified collection is empty.
 * <p>
 * Null returns true.
 *
 * @param coll  the collection to check, may be null
 * @return true if empty or null
 * @since Commons Collections 3.2
 */
public static boolean isEmpty(Collection coll) {
    return (coll == null || coll.isEmpty());
}
```

Comment: Apache Utills are absolutely great! Recently I discovered SpringUtils.join - very useful using on collections. Sorry for a little offtop :)

Answer (score 33):

No, `java.util.List.isEmpty()` doesn't check if a list is `null`.

If you are using the [Spring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) framework you can use the `CollectionUtils` class to check if a list is empty or not. It also takes care of the `null` references. Following is the code snippet from Spring framework's `CollectionUtils` class.

```
public static boolean isEmpty(Collection<?> collection) {
    return (collection == null || collection.isEmpty());
}
```

Even if you are not using Spring, you can go on and tweak this code to add in your `AppUtil` class.

Answer (score 21):

This **will** throw a `NullPointerException` - as will any attempt to invoke an instance method on a `null` reference - but in cases like this you should make an explicit check against `null`:

```
if ((test != null) && !test.isEmpty())
```

This is much better, and clearer, than propagating an `Exception`.

Comment: For a List, I sometimes use:  if ( eList != null && eList.size() > 0 )

Answer (score 11):

Invoking any method on any null reference will always result in an exception.  Test if the object is null first:

```
List<Object> test = null;
if (test != null && !test.isEmpty()) {
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, write a method to encapsulate this logic:

```
public static <T> boolean IsNullOrEmpty(Collection<T> list) {
    return list == null || list.isEmpty();
}
```

Then you can do:

```
List<Object> test = null;
if (!IsNullOrEmpty(test)) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: *"Does java.util.List.isEmpty() check if the list itself is null?"* seems pretty clear to me -- he is asking about the nullity of the list, not its contents.

Comment: Yeah, he totally confused me with such a strange question. I mean, the other way would also be dumb, because the check is for `if(!empty) then iterate`… But I deleted my stupid comment, before I saw your answer. Maybe he comes from PHP where we have `!empty($foo)` as somewhat an alias for `isset($foo) && $foo != ""`.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to [Lion's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512034/does-java-util-list-isempty-check-if-the-list-itself-is-null/11512091#11512091), I can say that you better use `if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(test)){...}`.

This also checks for null, so a manual check is not needed.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it will **throw an Exception**. Maybe you are used to **PHP** code, where `empty($element)` does also check for `isset($element)`. In Java this is not the case.

You can memorize that easily, because the method is directly called on the list (the method belongs to the list). So if there is no list, then there is no method. And Java will complain that there is no list to call this method on.

Answer (score 2):

You can use your own isEmpty (for multiple collection) method too. Add this to your Util class.

```
public static boolean isEmpty(Collection... collections) {
    for (Collection collection : collections) {
        if (null == collection || collection.isEmpty())
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you ought to rename it to `areEmpty()`? I find such methods/functions harder to use because they let some stuff slip through. Also, if the first `Collection` is null or empty and the rest are neither, you'd get an unexpected behavior.

Comment: What is the "Util class"? An existing class? Meant as a common noun? Something else?

Comment: `containsEmpty` would be the more appropriate name