# Difference between null and empty string

Tags: java, string, null, nullpointerexception

What is the difference between a null string (`String s = null`) and an empty string (`String s = ""`)?

This is what I have:

```
String s1 = ""; //print statement does not print any thing for s1 but s1.length()=0
String s2 = null;//print statement prints "null" for s2  but s2.length() gives exception
```

What does it mean?

Comment: This has been asked (and well-answered) before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802015/difference-between-null-and-java-string

Comment: @Eric yep it is similar question but my intention was to know why for s1.length() returns zero and s2.length() gives exception..but anyhow thanks i got some more detail info about this on the page linked by you..

Answer (score 75, accepted):

`String s1 = "";` means that the empty `String` is assigned to `s1`.
In this case, `s1.length()` is the same as `"".length()`, which will yield `0` as expected.

`String s2 = null;` means that (`null`) or "no value at all" is assigned to `s2`.  So this one, `s2.length()` is the same as `null.length()`, which will yield a `NullPointerException` as you can't call methods on `null` variables (pointers, sort of) in Java.

Also, a point, the statement

```
String s1;
```

Actually has the same effect as:

```
String s1 = null;
```

Whereas

```
String s1 = "";
```

Is, as said, a different thing.

Answer (score 10):

`Null` means nothing. Its just a literal. `Null` is the value of reference variable. But empty string is blank.It gives the `length=0`. Empty string is a blank value,means the string does not have any thing.

Answer (score 7):

No method can be invoked on a object which is assigned a `NULL` value. It will give a `nullPointerException`. Hence, `s2.length()` is giving an exception.

Comment: @Alexis Wilke : when String s = null+"a"; it gives output nulla but null.concat("a") it gives the null pointer exception. what is the reason in my first case null+""; is working

Comment: More or less, when you do `<object> + <string>` the compiler attempts a conversion of `<object>` to a string. Kind of like `<object>.toString() + <string>`, although for `null` that's a special case since you can't call a function from `null`.

Answer (score 4):

When Object variables are initially used in a language like Java, they have absolutely no value at all - not zero, but literally no value - that is `null`

For instance: `String s;`

If you were to use `s`, it would actually have a value of `null`, because it holds absolute nothing.

An empty string, however, is a value - it is a string of no characters.

```
String s; //Inits to null
String a =""; //A blank string
```

`Null` is essentially 'nothing' - it's the default 'value' (to use the term loosely) that Java assigns to any Object variable that was not initialized.

`Null` isn't really a value - and as such, doesn't have properties. So, calling anything that is meant to return a value - such as `.length()`, will invariably return an error, because 'nothing' cannot have properties.

To go into more depth, by creating `s1 = "";` you are initializing an object, which can have properties, and takes up relevant space in memory.  By using `s2;` you are designating that variable name to be a String, but are not actually assigning any value at that point.

Comment: this explanation is really broken. a value type cannot be null.

Comment: @carlosdc Can you elaborate? What do you mean a value type cannot be null?

Comment: try int i = null; in java.

Comment: Oh you mean that you can't assign a value of null?

Comment: exactly. not to int, char, double, float, short or boolean. you're trying to simplify the explanation too much, and it is just wrong.

Comment: @Singular1ty - See this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5

Comment: @carlosdc Fixed up the my post a bit.