# Access VBA: sql character to VBA string

Tags: ms-access, vba

I would like to loop through a recordset in Access VBA and extract the values of a variable as a string in VBA. This won't work:

```
Sub test()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim m As String

Set rs = CurrentDb.openrecordset("myTable")

If Not (rs.EOF And rs.bof) Then
rs.movefirst

Do Until rs.EOF
debug.print rs!myField 'works
MsgBox rs!myField 'doesn't work

rs.movenext
Loop

End If

rs.Close

End Sub
```

It gives me an error with the msgbox about nulls, but it works fine for debug.print. I can't seem to extract the `rs!myField` into a VBA string variable. The character variable in the table contains null values, but I should be able to still work with it.

Comment: Try something like: `myStr = rs.Fields("MyField").value` Then use myStr it in your MsgBox.

Comment: I get the same error when I assign the value to `myStr`, but `debug.print` works with your code FWIW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see the issue. `Null` isn't the same thing as `vbNullString`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620354/difference-between-null-and-empty-string) for more information. It's Java, but the idea holds.

You have to handle the `Null` occurrence with an if statement like this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim rs    As DAO.Recordset: Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("myTable")
    Dim MyStr As String
    If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then rs.MoveFirst

    Do Until rs.EOF
        If IsNull(rs!MyField) Then
            MyStr = vbNullString
        Else
            MyStr = rs!MyField
        End If
        MsgBox (MyStr)
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    rs.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have nullable fields and want to treat them as text in VBA, you can "coalesce" them by appending `vbNullString`:

```
MsgBox rs!myField & vbNullString
```

Concatenation changes the value of the expression to `String` before it wraps it's passed to `MsgBox`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply do MsgBox nz(rs!myField,"Value if null")