# NullPointerException occurs when going through methods

Tags: java, runtime-error

I'm trying to figure out some basics in Java. The code I've typed below compiles just fine, but not running.
Everytime the code runs, it says `NullPointerException` error occurs.

```
class testOnStrings {
    public static void main (String args []){
        String input, output;

        // isWordPalindrome
        input = "forever eating cheese";
        boolean boolOutput = isWordPalindrome(input);
        System.out.println("\n" + input + (boolOutput ? " is " : " is not ") + "a word palindrome");

        input = "fall leaves when leaves fall";
        boolOutput = isWordPalindrome(input);
        System.out.println("\n" + input + (boolOutput ? " is " : " is not ") + "a word palindrome");

        input = null;
        boolOutput = isWordPalindrome(input);
        System.out.println("\n" + input + (boolOutput ? " is " : " is not ") + "a word palindrome");
    }

    static String reverseWords(String input) {
        // My code
        String words[] = input.split(" ");
        String reverseWord = "";
        for (int pointer = words.length - 1; pointer >= 0; pointer--)
            reverseWord += words [pointer] + " ";
        return reverseWord;
    }

    static boolean isWordPalindrome(String input) {
        // My code
        String reverseWordInput = reverseWords(input);
        boolean isPalindrome = input.equals(reverseWordInput);
        return isPalindrome;
    }
}
```

There is an error when running the code.

```
Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at idle.reverseWords(idle.java:21)
    at idle.isWordPalindrome(idle.java:30)
    at idle.main(idle.java:15)
```

Please help because the compilation is successful but code is not running

Comment: You are passing null as input which is causing NPE.  Please use debugger for this type of debugging

Comment: Put a protection for null inputs on _**static String reverseWords(String input)**_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend handling special/corner cases in the method rather than expecting callers to behave with empty or `null` string.

You can enhance `isWordPalindrome` method to handle `null`, `zero` or `single` character so that any kind of input can be handled.

**FROM**

```
static boolean isWordPalindrome(String input) {
    // My code
    String reverseWordInput = reverseWords(input);
    boolean isPalindrome = input.equals(reverseWordInput);
    return isPalindrome;
}
```

**TO**

```
static boolean isWordPalindrome(String input) {
    // My code
    if (input == null || input.length() == 0 || input.length() == 1) return true;
    String reverseWordInput = reverseWords(input);
    boolean isPalindrome = input.equals(reverseWordInput);
    return isPalindrome;
}
```

Above enhancement will also avoid calling `reverseWords` for `null`, `zero` or `single` character.

On same note, I would also enhance `reverseWords` also.

**FROM**

```
static String reverseWords(String input) {
    // My code
    String words[] = input.split(" ");
    String reverseWord = "";
    for (int pointer = words.length - 1; pointer >= 0; pointer--)
        reverseWord += words [pointer] + " ";
    return reverseWord;
}
```

**TO**

```
static String reverseWords(String input) {
    // My code
    if (input == null || input.length() == 0 || input.length() == 1) return input;
    String words[] = input.split(" ");
    String reverseWord = "";
    for (int pointer = words.length - 1; pointer >= 0; pointer--)
        reverseWord += words [pointer] + " ";
    return reverseWord;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have assigned `input` as  `null` hence the issue

```
input = null;
boolOutput = isWordPalindrome(input);
```

assign empty string value to input in case you don't want anything

```
input = "";
boolOutput = isWordPalindrome(input);
```

Reference :

[Difference between null and empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620354/difference-between-null-and-empty-string)