# How to use ternary operator to check if a String is empty in a simple way

Tags: flutter, dart

I will show in 10 Text widgets, some variables. This variables can are Strings and can be empty ''

There is a simpler way to do this verification than this, one by one: ?

```dart
object.name.isNotEmpty ? object.name :  "not typed"
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

check if it is null string

```
object.name ?? 'default value'
```

check if its a null or empty string

```
object.name?.isEmpty ?? 'default value'
```

The `??` double question mark operator means "if null". Take the following expression, for example. `String a = b ?? 'hello';` This means a equals b, but if b is null then a equals 'hello'.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: `type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

Answer (score 1):

```
object.name ??= "not typed";
```

It assigns *"not typed"* if `object.name` is empty.

You can also use double question mark to check if something else is null and if it is assign the other value:

```
object.name = null ?? "not typed"; // result: object.name = "not typed";
object.name = "typed" ?? "not typed"; // result: object.name = "typed";
```

EDIT:

If you need to check if something is an empty string, you can use tenary expression, but there is no more [operators](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#operators) or [string methods](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/String-class.html):

```
object.name = object.name != null && object.name.isNotEmpty ? object.name : "not typed";
```

Comment: It doesn't work too. My variables are empty strings

Comment: So, not if String is null, but if string is empty. This is a [huge difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620354/difference-between-null-and-empty-string)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the most convenient way to provide a default value is to extend the String class.

So, create a class `StringExtension` with a method like this:

```
extension StringExtension on String {
  String def(String defaultValue) {
    return isNotEmpty ? this : defaultValue;
  }
}
```

In your view, you can now simply do:

```
import 'package:code/helpers/string_extension.dart';
String value;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Text(value.def("Unknown"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to simply check if something is null and assign to a variable accordingly. To do this you can use the OR operator like this:

```js
var x = object.name || "not typed"
```

if `object.name` is truthy (as in not an empty string `""`) then that will be assigned to your variable (in this case `x`). If `object.name` is an empty string/falsey then `"not-typed"` will be assigned to `x`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it throws this `error: The operands of the operator '||' must be assignable to 'bool'.`

Comment: My variables are all strings and no one is null, some are "" empty

Comment: Unlike C, C++, Python, etc., Dart does not have permissive notions of "truthy" and "falsey".  Only booleans are allowed in boolean expressions.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a string is null or not by using ternary operator in JS you can use:

```js
let n = ""

console.log(n.length > 0 ? "The string is not empty" : "The string is empty");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

object.name != Null ? object.name :  "not typed"

or

object.name != '' ? object.name :  "not typed"