# Setting a character limit for a string using Java annotations

Tags: java, jboss, seam

I'm trying to create a string with a character length restriction of 12 for my JBOSS Seam project. The string must either be 12 characters or blank. My length annotation is correct which is the following:

```
    @Length(min = 12,max = 12)
```

However when I try to put a null value in there I get an InvalidStateException: validation fail error. Any ideas how to allow this?

Comment: Did you try using `@Nullable` annotation?

Comment: Tried this did not help. Same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I decided to not rely on the @Length annotation and instead created my own custom validator class to do the job and that worked out well. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Null value for String and empty String are not the same thing.  You are passing a null value (not a String of length 0).  Check this out:

[Difference between null and empty ("") Java String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802015/difference-between-null-and-java-string)

Also, you should try out @Size(min=,max=).

Comment: The size part isn't the issue. It correctly allows only 12 characters and anything less or more will produce a warning. It's the null scenario that gets the error.

Comment: Need sugestion, how do I apply check of Integer only using @Size?
Does hibernate provide any such Annotation allowing combination of maxLength and numbersOnly?