# Diffrence between String str = "' & String str =null

Tags: java, string

What is the differences between `String str1=""` and `String str2 =null`?
 When we print `str1` there is no output and when we print `str2` output is `null`.

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking here... one is a reference to a `String` object with a length of 0, and one is a null reference (i.e. not a reference to an object at all)

Comment: @vikeng21 What do you mean by `null` not being "valid"?

Comment: Already asked question..Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802015/difference-between-null-and-java-string

Comment: @ Tichodroma i meant what you have excatly answered

Answer (score 5):

`""` is the empty string, [`null` is the null reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java).

Comment: @sotcha - `""` is a *String Literal*, it will go into the String constants pool. It is not equal to `new String()`

Comment: @TheLostMind you got right, it is not equal, it's equivalent (as the documentation says). If I create many "" objects with point to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

The first is an empty `String` whereas the second is a `null` reference to a `String`.

An empty `String` is a `String` with no characters.

A `null` reference is a reference to a `String` that is not existent.

Comment: if A null reference is a reference to a String that is not existent,than how System.out.print(str) give output as like null

Comment: @GauriShankar null is handled as a special case, explicitly. Check out the docs for [String.valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)): `if the argument is null, then a string equal to "null"; otherwise, the value of obj.toString() is returned.`

Comment: A null reference is a reference to *nothing* (null).

Answer (score 1):

There Huge Difference **""** means this empty String and Second one **null** means there is noting to assign and its noting exists.

Answer (score 1):

**""** means strings is created in [string pool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2486195/821057) while for second one is nothing exist.

> str1 there is no output

because string is empty so its printing nothing to output while second is null so its string value is null.

Answer (score 0):

The first you are creating a new String object and assigning it "" or empty String.  Your variable is pointing to this string object.  The second you are not creating a new String object.  You are creating a pointer that is not pointing to anything it is null.  When you print using "" + yourstring it will print null because of the base Class objects toString() method.