# String with value null and memory allocation

Tags: java, string, null, heap-memory

If a String Object references to a null value, is there any memory allocated for this value?

e.g. `String str = ""; String str = null;`

str's value is null, or empty String, is this allocated somewhere?

**TEXT ADDED**  what happens when a String reference points to null (how do you specify this null and still not allocating memory for this "specification"?), how is this information stored? because the reference is practically storing an address.

Comment: Actually, you've allocated a value to `str`, being `""`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802015/difference-between-null-and-java-string

Comment: `str's value is null, or empty String` I hope you know that both doesn't mean the same ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case -1 :**

```
String s = null;
```

here, memory is allocated only for the reference s. `null` is not an object. So no memory is allocared for that.

**Case -2  :**

```
String s = ""; // empty string
```

Here, memory is allocated to both String reference `s` as well as the actual String value `""` (Yes, `""` is different from `null`)

Comment: so then the reference points to null, how this is stored? because the reference is practically storing an address

Comment: @aurelius - In JVM, the references which point to null are handled differently. So, if you have `String s = null`, the underlying byte code instruction would be `aconst_null` followed by `astore_1`(store null reference in variable `s`). This means `null` values are handled in a different way using a different opcode.

Comment: so practically, if the JVM generates some code, specific for this null values, then there is some memory allocated...

Comment: @aurelius - 1. Here,the *compiler* generates code which will be *run* by the JVM :). Next, don't get confused between *instructions* and *objects*. `aconst_null` is an *instruction*. There is no object called `null` which occupies memory. Only the field (`s`) in which this null reference  is loaded will occupy 4 bytes / 8 bytes depending on whether the system is 32 bits or 64 bits.

Comment: so if you do String s = null; then the s reference (address) will be null? --- i am a bit confused now...

Comment: @aurelius -  No. The reference will not be null. The value to which the reference `s` points will be `null`. Reference is like a *sign board*, it always points to something. It can either point to `Sydney` or point `upwards towards nothing in particular` :P

Comment: so then, from "The value to which the reference s points will be null" null is a value located somewhere in memory...?

Comment: @aurelius - No. `aconst_null` is an instruction. It pushes a *null reference* on to the stack. So, `a null reference itself is different from normal references`.

Comment: ok, i think i get it now... the "s" reference which points to null, is a reference that is pushed in a "null" references location from stack, and that's how the JVM threats it different, and knows that the value to which the reference points too is null? Is this how it goes?

Comment: @aurelius - The `null` constant reference is pushed *into the variable s*.

Comment: ok, got it, thank you so much, all the best!

Answer (score 2):

```
String nullObj = null;
String emptyStr= ""
```

Both are completely different.

In case of `null`, it refers to nothing. But still memory allocates. `null` takes 4 bytes if it is 32-bit systems and 8 bytes if it is 64-bit system.

For empty string (`""`), that's 100% a String object and memory allocates.

Comment: Though in case of `""` it might already get allocated (interned) and just a reference is there.

Comment: and for String str = null; there is no memory allocation, keep in mind that you need to store somewhere this value...