# Double Quotes only in java String (without space) ""

Tags: java, string

Was doing some Java code,What I tried was:

```
 public class Tester {
 public static void main(String args[]){
       String str = "";
       System.out.println(str.length());
   }
 }
```

and the length was as expected **zero**.
and then  I tried something like following

```
public class Tester {
public static void main(String args[]){
   String str = ""+""+""+""+"";
   System.out.println(str.length());
 }   
}
```

and the String length was again **zero**.
So whats that **""** thing is.
What this append operation ""+""+""+""+"" is doing here.
I hope it is doing something but the length was again **Zero**.
I am not understanding these ***double quotes without any spaces***.

### There is something there,that is why it is **not null**,but whatever it is,it is of zero length,....not able to swallow this thing

EDIT:
Why using empty Strings?Why not relying on null ?Just looking for clarifications....Although I am afraid of **null** ghost too :(

Comment: simple math : 0 + 0 = 0

Comment: But there is something,thats why it is not null,but whatever it is,it is of zero length,hOW COME

Comment: I'm not sure why this seems strange to you. A string literal in Java is basically equivalent to whatever there is between the quotes, not including them. Since that is nothing, then it's empty, and its length is zero. What's the problem with that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802015/difference-between-null-and-java-string

Comment: I think you are confusing the value and the internal representation of the object.  True, there's an object, `String`, that exists but it's value is nothing.  So if I take the sum of, or concatenate, multiple instance of nothing, I'll get a new object that has the value of nothing.  That value is a zero-length `String` instance.

Comment: @MadConan This can be an acceptable answer

Answer (score 3):

Double quotes mean an empty string - A string with with nothing in it.

As Lrrr commented, nothing + nothing + nothing is still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Double quote without any character means empty `String` in Java. If you concat multiple empty `String` values result will again be an empty `String`. That is why you are getting `str.length()` as zero everytime.

Answer (score 1):

If you do `+ ""` with anything, to performs the `toString()`, `""` is empty string, no matter how many empty strings you concatenate , it ll always be an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

String literal assignment in java takes `""` as empty string. Which means, there is an object without any content in it.

Method length() actually returns the size of the underlying array of String, which in this case is 0.

So if you add a lot of empty strings, the answer you will get is just 0