# Value of two quotes with no space ""

Tags: java

In my computer science class we were discussing null and values when we came across a predicament. We could not figure out the value of simply 2 quotes with no space as "". Just wondering if anyone would know what the exact value of "". Thanks

Comment: consider `String test = "";
     System.out.println(test.hashCode());`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458491/double-quotes-only-in-java-string-without-space

Answer (score 1):

It's the empty `String`. [JLS-3.10.5. String Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) says *A string literal consists of zero or more characters enclosed in double quotes.* And, then includes this example

> *The following are examples of string literals:*
>
> ```
> ""                    // the empty string
> ```

As Java `String`(s) are immutable, it has a constant length of `0` and stores a sequence of `0` characters.

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize it with `null` like this:

```
String s1 = null;
```

It means that no object is assigned to variable `s1`. However, when you initialize it with empty String like this:

```
String s2 = "";
```

It means that a String object is assigned to `s2` (although empty).

Now if you want to perform any operation, let's say you want to call the `.equals(..)` method of string, then it will throw `NullPointerException` in the former case as there is not String object. However, it will work fine in latter because there is an object there, it doesn't matter whether it's empty or not

```
s1.equals("something"); // throws NullPointerException
s2.equals("something"); // works fine
```