# Exit while loop using null

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, null

I need to enter a random amount of numbers from 0-500, once the return is an empty string, I need to exit the loop and do some calculations with the inputs. Here's my code so far:

```
String test = "";

while(test != null ){
    String[] inputs = br.readLine().split("\\s+");
    inputs[0] = test;

    if (test != null){
        inputs2[i] = Integer.parseInt(inputs[0]);
        StatsPackage.inputs[i] = Integer.parseInt(inputs[0]);
    }
    i++; 
}//end of while loop
```

Here is the error I keep getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)

at StatsPackage.main(StatsPackage.java:84)
```

Line 84 is this:

```
inputs2[i] = Integer.parseInt(inputs[0]);
```

any ideas?

Comment: `Integer.parseInt("");` this is what you are doing you will always get exception for that because `test` never changed

Comment: Check [Difference between null and empty (“”) Java String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802015/difference-between-null-and-empty-java-string)

Comment: I'd like to understand the intent of your code, as the fact that you didn't understand the difference between `empty` and `null`, plus the use of `inputs2` variable, is leading me to believe there are much better design options that you're still unaware of as a beginner (?), and that would make your code much better.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?  Specifically, what is the value of `test`?

Answer (score -2):

You could verify if the string is not empty adding:

```
String test = "";

while(test != null && !test.isEmpty()){
String[] inputs = br.readLine().split("\\s+");
inputs[0] = test;

if (test != null){
    inputs2[i] = Integer.parseInt(inputs[0]);
    StatsPackage.inputs[i] = Integer.parseInt(inputs[0]);
}
i++; 
}//end of while loop
```

Comment: Very obvious problem with the loops' conditional and the `test` variable starting state.

Answer (score -2):

Just try the following comparison in your code:

```
(test != null || !(test.equals("")))
```

In this case, you are avoiding NULL references and empty strings ("").

Hope this answer is helpful!

Comment: The check for empty doesn't need to be wrapped in a second parenthesis, and it would be better to use `String.isEmpty()` instead. Also, this doesn't really answer what's wrong with his code, and doesn't explicitly teach anything. I don't want to discourage you; but you're providing a solution here, not an answer.

Comment: Respectfully i say: He is requesting any idea to solve the issue, so this is a solution. I only tried to provide a solution of many that can be possible in this case. 

Likewise, i agree with you in the use of {String.isEmpty()}