# Difference between initializing variables with null or 0 or ""

Tags: java, variables, null, initialization

Could anyone provide simple example when and where to declare `null` or `0` or `""` while declaring variables in java? I went through some examples but didn't understand, so can anyone explain clearly with some simple examples?

Comment: [Difference between null and empty (“”) Java String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802015/difference-between-null-and-empty-java-string)

Comment: Well, you can only assign `0` to a primitive numeric or boxed primitive numeric type. You can only assign `""` to a string reference. You can assign any object reference to `null`.

Answer (score 2):

- Class variables, instance variables, or array components are [initialized for you](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) <sub>(non-final ones)</sub>, so there is no need to initialize them to `false`/`null`/`0` (it will be redundant):

  > Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a default value when it is created ([§15.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9), [§15.10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10)):
- You **need** to initialize local variables though:

  > Local variables are slightly different; the compiler never assigns a default value to an uninitialized local variable. If you cannot initialize your local variable where it is declared, make sure to assign it a value before you attempt to use it. Accessing an uninitialized local variable will result in a compile-time error.
- If you want an empty string for instance, use `String myStr = "";`

Answer (score 1):

for declaring a string you can use "".

for declaring any other non primitive data type you can use null (be careful about null pointer exception).

for numeric data type like `byte`, `int` use can use 0.

Comment: You *can* assign a String the initial value `""`, but this value is completely different to giving it the value `null`. Perhaps you can expand upon the difference.

Answer (score 1):

`Null` - This can be assigned to all non-primitives type (just to indicate that this is not referring to any object, and can throw null pointer)

`" "` - Only for String Literal

> Zero can be assigned to all the primitives and Numeric Wrappers /Boxed Primitives

```
char zeroChar = 0;
float zeroFloat = 0;
double zeroDouble = 0;
short zeroShort = 0;
long  zeroLong = 0;
byte zeroByte = 0;
int zeroInt = 0;
```