# Null is added in the beginning of the String when using BufferedReader

Tags: java, android, inputstream

I am using `BufferedReader` to get a `String` from a `.txt` File

```
 BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(name)));
    BufferedReader count = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(name)));

    String line;
    String str =  null;

    while((line = count.readLine()) != null)
    {
        str += read.readLine() + "\n";

    }
```

Than I display that `String` in a `TextView` 
But it displays null and than my `String`

`nullThis is file 1`
rather than
`This is file 1`

How can I fix this??

Comment: Why not using `StringBuilder` to read data from Stream?

Comment: `str = null` followed by `str += something`, which at the time means `str = null + something`, and you wonder why you get `null` in your string???

Comment: _str +=_ is wrong.

Comment: @MarkYisri Why you say so?

Comment: because you are adding a null. use a stringbuilder instead.

Comment: or change it to "" instead of null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out!

```
BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(name)));
BufferedReader count = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(name)));

String line;
String str = "";

while((line=count.readLine())!=null)

{
    str += read.readLine() + "\n";

}
```

Comment: Ohh...  I thought `String = null` sets the `String` to equal nothing.

Comment: @Eddie just follow [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802015/difference-between-null-and-empty-java-string) and you will get a very clear idea.

Answer (score 4):

You are using:

```
String str = null;
```

And then

```
str += read.readLine() + "\n";
```

Which is

```
str = str + read.readLine() + "\n";
```

So, after variable substitution, we get:

```
str = null + read.readLine() + "\n";
```

And this means we join it with null, which produces `"null"` intentionally.

Try one of these lines (**only one**):

```
String str = "";
String str = new String ();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `StringBuilder` instead of `String`. It has better performance since `String` is immutable.

*[use `StringBuffer` if you want it to be thread safe]*.

```
BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(name)));
    BufferedReader count = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(name)));

    String line;
    StringBuilder str =  new StringBuilder();

    while((line = count.readLine()) != null)
    {
        str.append(read.readLine()).append("\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Initialize it like

```
String str = "";
```