# Difference between setting null string values and empty string in Hbase?

Tags: json, solr, hive, hbase

I'm trying to see the difference between null string values and empty strings. In any case, Hbase shows me the same value =, how could I see the difference between a null and an empty string? When I send per example toto1 = "" and toto2 = null, Hbase shows me the same thing, is there any way to differentiate the two data?

Thank you in advance

Best regards,

Comment: This link might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802015/difference-between-null-and-empty-java-string

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Java code then you can try isEmpty()  method of String to check the string is empty or not.