# if (String != null && !String.isEmpty()) not working for checking null

Tags: java, android, string

I am checking String whether it's null or not but I don't know why it's always enter into `if block`

```
 Log.d(TAG,"String ID  "+str);
 if (str!= null && !str.isEmpty()){
    Log.d(TAG,"String ID is not Null ");                 
 } else {
    Log.d(TAG,"String ID is Null ");            
 }
```

I also generate logs to check String value before checking if condition and it shows like this

```
01-06 07:17:46.128 30321-30376/com.example D/### String Checker ###: Page ID  null
01-06 07:17:46.128 30321-30376/com.example D/### String Checker ###: Page ID is not Null
```

**Update:**
Setting String to `null` then calling other class like this

```
String str = null;
new AsyncTask(searchInterfaceChat,getActivity(),String.valueOf(str)).execute(query);
```

Comment: Is this the actual code?

Comment: what is the value of the string?

Comment: @ScaryWombat is just to show that it's string to avoid confusion

Comment: @ButI'mNotAWrapperClass check update values

Comment: maybe the value of `str` is `null`

Comment: In your updated code, `str` is not used

Comment: @ScaryWombat sorry for the confusion please check again

Comment: write your code as `new AsyncTask(searchInterfaceChat,getActivity(), str).execute(query);`

Comment: `System.out.println(String.valueOf(str));` will print the String *null*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While looking into your logs, it seems the value of your string is "null". your string is not null. Check into that. This observation is only for your logs

---

After your update of code, problem is `String.valueOf(str)`, it is converting null to "null" which is actually a String. Only pass `str`, not `String.valueOf(str)`, 
like `new AsyncTask(searchInterfaceChat,getActivity(), str).execute(query);`

---

> Updates for little bit explanation

If you look into code `String.valueOf()`, it returns `"null"` not `null` if in case of null Object. So for you, it is actually `"null"` which is being printed correctly on the log, but making confusion. Below is code

```
/**
 * Returns the string representation of the {@code Object} argument.
 *
 * @param   obj   an {@code Object}.
 * @return  if the argument is {@code null}, then a string equal to
 *          {@code "null"}; otherwise, the value of
 *          {@code obj.toString()} is returned.
 * @see     java.lang.Object#toString()
 */
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

You can read [Difference between null and empty ("") Java String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802015/difference-between-null-and-empty-java-string/) which not exact QA, but you can get some idea about `"null"` and `null`

Comment: The output before the `if` is `Page ID  null`, so I think that your second assumption is not correct.

Comment: *it seems value of your string is "null"* - yep as per my comment below the main question.

Comment: Can you tell me the reason behind this even when in log it says string is null

Comment: No log is saying "null" not null. Understand the difference between both. null denotes a string without memory, but "null" denotes string is not empty and it has value "null".

Answer (score 4):

You are passing the String value *null* as this is what will be returned by `String.valueOf(str);`  when `str` is `null`

Comment: Can you tell me the reason behind this even when in log it's says string is null

Comment: The log is simply printing out the String value `null` - the same as if you had declared `String str = "null";`

Comment: it's not `String str = "null" its `String = null` without any quotes

Answer (score 2):

if we want to know, we can look at the source code. the String `isEmpty` method returns true if the string length is zero.

```
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        // Android-changed: Get length from count field rather than value array (see above).
        // Empty string has {@code count == 0} with or without string compression enabled.
        // return value.length == 0;
        return count == 0;
    }
```

the method `String.valueOf` will return a "null" if you object is null.

```
/**
     * @return  if the argument is {@code null}, then a string equal to
     *          {@code "null"}; otherwise, the value of
     *          {@code obj.toString()} is returned.
     * @see     java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
 public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
        return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
    }
```

so when you use it in other class, it return the string not null.

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use TextUtils.isEmpty() it will check both of your condition.

```
 if (!TextUtils.isEmpty("your string")){
Log.d(TAG,"String ID is not Null ");                 
 } else {
   Log.d(TAG,"String ID is Null ");            
    }
```

Also pass the string because in you case you are doing with th string class.

Tried with String s=null and s="ad" value working fine in both case :

```
 public class Main
 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
 String str ="ss";
 if (str!=null&&!str.isEmpty()){
System.out.println("not Null");               
} else {
      System.out.println(" Null");               
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this way but i need to know why i am getting into if block

Answer (score 1):

Bring the **null** first so that It don't give error.

When `str` is not `null` it's ok

**But**

if `str` is `null`

and you write `str!=null` the it will first try to read `str` but it is `null` 
so it will give an error.

```
if (null!=str  && !str.isEmpty()){
   Log.d(TAG,"String ID is not Null ");                 
} else {
   Log.d(TAG,"String ID is Null ");            
}
```