# String returning StringIndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: java, string, substring

I have two string

```
String s1 = "";
String s2 = "";
Boolean check = s1 != null && s2 != null && s1.substring(1) != null;
 then return check;
```

Why this code is throwing StringIndexOutOfBoundException?
If s1 ="" then why it is checking for s1.substring(1) != null when s1 != null is false ? It should return false not throw Exception?
How to resolve this?

Comment: an empty string "" has a different meaning than a `null`, they are not same

Comment: would be easier to have your boolean check for StringUtils.isNotBlank(s1) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(s2)

Comment: Possibly related: [Difference between null and empty (“”) Java String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4802015)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A null string is not the same as an empty string. In Java, the String class possesses a method for checking if a String is empty. Rewrite your empty checks as `!s1.isEmpty() && !s2.isEmpty()`.

Similarly, a substring doesn't return null. It can return an empty string if the index is the string's length, but otherwise will throw an exception for invalid indexes. Perhaps you meant to check `s1.substring(1).isEmpty()` in that last condition? In saying that, as far as I can tell that is equivalent to checking if `s1.length() > 1`, which is a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below two functions for an empty string check.

```
                StringUtils.isEmpty(str)
                StringUtils.isBlank(str)
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, a null-check is incorporated in the isBlank() function.

Comment: Yes null check is included in isBlank function

Answer (score 0):

The program is returning an error because the first 2 conditions of the boolean are true, "" and null are not the same, so the program keeps checking all the conditions, but maybe substring is returning an error because you can not substring a string with lenght 0.