# When to use empty values ("",0) vs null in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, null

What is the difference between this data class

```
data class Greeting(
     val name: String,
     val country: String? = null
)
```

VS

```
data class Greeting(
     val name: String,
     val country: String = ""
)
```

Is their any preferred way when we use null and empty values such as "",0

Comment: This is opinionated, but don't ever use `0` or `""` as an indicator that there is no value. This is just confusing and error-prone. Use nulls instead. The only situation where I could choose empty value instead of null is empty collection. Depending on the case empty list may be easier to handle than null.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between null and empty ("") Java String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802015/difference-between-null-and-empty-java-string)

Comment: @broot Strong agree on 0, strong disagree about “” in some situations.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yes, I guess there are such cases. For example, search query when searching through some data. Conceptually, we assume search query is always there, but empty string is understood as "no filtering".